# Why does defining __getitem__ on a class make it iterable in python?

Tags: python, iterator, overloading

Why does defining `__getitem__` on a class make it iterable?

For instance if I write:

```
class B:
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return k
    
cb = B()
        
for k in cb:
    print k
```

I get the output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
...
```

I would really expect to see an error returned from `for k in cb:`.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If you take a look at [PEP234](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234) defining iterators, it says:

> 1. An object can be iterated over with `for` if it implements `__iter__()` or `__getitem__()`.
> 2. An object can function as an iterator if it implements `next()`.

Answer (score 83):

Iteration's support for `__getitem__` can be seen as a "legacy feature" which allowed smoother transition when [PEP234](https://peps.python.org/pep-0234/) introduced iterability as a primary concept. It only applies to classes without `__iter__` whose `__getitem__` accepts integers 0, 1, &c, and raises `IndexError` once the index gets too high (if ever), typically "sequence" classes coded before `__iter__` appeared (though nothing stops you from coding new classes this way too).

Personally, I would rather not rely on this in new code, though it's not deprecated nor is it going away (works fine in Python 3 too), so this is just a matter of style and taste ("explicit is better than implicit" so I'd rather explicitly support iterability rather than rely on `__getitem__` supporting it implicitly for me -- but, not a bigge).

Comment: When `__getitem__` was introduced to create iterables, was it done with `[]` attribute access in mind? From reading the answers, it seems to me that if you want `[]` attribute access _and_ an iterable you cannot do this using only `__getitem__`. You should then use `__getitem__` for `[]` access and `__iter__` for the iterator, correct?

Comment: Another point against `__getitem__` is that any integer type is going to have an upper limit, so indexed access could bump into that. Whereas `__next__` can keep going happily ad infinitum. (At least, that's my understanding.)

Comment: Just noting that pythons int has no limit. It is an arbitrary size integer.

Answer (score 44):

`__getitem__` predates the iterator protocol, and was in the past the *only* way to make things iterable.  As such, it's still supported as a method of iterating.  Essentially, the protocol for iteration is:

1. Check for an `__iter__` method.  If it exists, use the new iteration protocol.
2. Otherwise, try calling `__getitem__` with successively larger integer values until it raises IndexError.

(2) used to be the only way of doing this, but had the disadvantage that it assumed more than was needed to support just iteration.  To support iteration, you had to support random access, which was much more expensive for things like files or network streams where going forwards was easy, but going backwards would require storing everything.  `__iter__` allowed iteration without random access, but since random access usually allows iteration anyway, and because breaking backward compatability would be bad, `__getitem__` is still supported.

Comment: yes, thank you, this answered "if it ain't broken why fix it?" question I had.

Answer (score 8):

Special methods such as `__getitem__` add special behaviors to objects, including iteration.

[http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.**getitem**](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)

"for loops expect that an IndexError will be raised for illegal indexes to allow proper detection of the end of the sequence."

Raise IndexError to signal the end of the sequence.

Your code is basically equivalent to:

```
i = 0
while True:
    try:
        yield object[i]
        i += 1
    except IndexError:
        break
```

Where object is what you're iterating over in the for loop.

Answer (score 5):

This is so for historical reasons. Prior to Python 2.2 __getitem__ was the only way to create a class that could be iterated over with the for loop. In 2.2 the __iter__ protocol was added but to retain backwards compatibility __getitem__ still works in for loops.

Answer (score 1):

Because `cb[0]` is the same as `cb.__getitem__(0)`. See the [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) on this.

Comment: True, but __getitem__() is not the same as __iter__().