# How can I make a class in python support __getitem__, but not allow iteration?

Tags: python, operator-overloading, iteration

I want to define a class that supports `__getitem__`, but does not allow iteration.
for example:

```
class B:
   def __getitem__(self, k):
      return k

cb = B()

for x in cb:
   print x
```

What could I add to the class `B` to force the `for x in cb:` to fail?

Comment: Just asking this, and answering it, in case someone else needs to know how to do this.

Comment: Out of curiosity, *why* do you want to give access to getitem but not make it iterable? What was your use-case?

Comment: I have a class which acts like, but does not inherit from, a dictionary.  Therefore I define __getitem__, and if someone tries to iterate over it, I want it to error, rather than start trying to call __getitem__ with whole numbers. Just to be clear, this is not how I would have chosen to implement this particular class, but my decision was overridden.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think a slightly better solution would be to raise a TypeError rather than a plain exception (this is what normally happens with a non-iterable class:

```
class A(object):
    # show what happens with a non-iterable class with no __getitem__
    pass

class B(object):
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return k
    def __iter__(self):
        raise TypeError('%r object is not iterable'
                        % self.__class__.__name__)
```

Testing:

```
>>> iter(A())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'A' object is not iterable
>>> iter(B())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "iter.py", line 9, in __iter__
    % self.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: 'B' object is not iterable
```

Comment: +1 for the proper use of new-style classes (as well as the overall goodness of the approach).

Comment: Sadly, this makes isinstance(a, collections.Iterable) return True :(

Answer (score 2):

From the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926574/why-does-defining-getitem-on-a-class-make-it-iterable-in-python), we can see that __iter__ will be called before __getitem__ if it exists, so simply define B as:

```
class B:
   def __getitem__(self, k):
      return k

   def __iter__(self):
      raise Exception("This class is not iterable")
```

Then:

```
cb = B()
for x in cb: # this will throw an exception when __iter__ is called.
  print x
```

Comment: If there is a more pythonic answer than this I would gladly accept it.

Comment: have you class name properly capitalised, that'd be more pythonic