# Does Python provide "free" default iterators?

Tags: python, iterator, default

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does defining **getitem** on a class make it iterable in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926574/why-does-defining-getitem-on-a-class-make-it-iterable-in-python)

I have a class that is basically a wrapper for a python list. Within this class I have defined `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, and `__len__` . I have not defined `__iter__` for this class.

when I go:

```
thing = ListWrapper(range(4))
for i in thing :
    print i
```

I get the output:

```
0
1
2
3
```

Which is nice, but I expected an error message of some sort saying that python could not find an iterator. I've given the documentation a look and can't find anything referencing default iterators. Furthermore, tracing through the code in PyDev shows that it is calling the `__getitem__` method each iteration.

I was wondering if it is good practice to depend on this behavior in my code. It doesn't fell quite right to me at this point. Does Python guarantee that classes with `__getitem__` and `__len__` will be treated as if they have a defined iterator? Any other information on weirdness this may cause is also welcome.

Comment: @Ned Thanks, that's what I was looking for, but couldn't find. Ah, the finicky nature of search terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a class doesn't have `__iter__`, but does have `__getitem__`, the iteration machinery will call it with consecutive integers until it runs out.