# Retrieving data from QModelIndex causes endless loop

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qmodelindex

I'm having problems with a class that implements `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`.

Instances of this class are the data backend of a `QAbstractListModel`. I return these instances in the `data(index)` implementation of the Model when `role==Qt.UserRole` to be able to access the object from outside the model.

One scenario where I want to do this, is when the user clicks on any item in the `QListView` that uses my model for displaying the data. The problem now is, that my program starts running in an endless loop (within `__getattr__`) as soon as I try to retrieve the data from the index that the user clicked on.

Below is a complete, copy/pasteable code fragment that reproduces the behaviour described. The program will loop in the line `index.data(Qt.UserRole)` of `testfunc`.

Am I missing a point somewhere or have I encountered a bug in PySide?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from PySide.QtCore import QAbstractListModel, Qt, QObject
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QListView

import sys

###############################################################################

class TestObject(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Creates new instance of TestObject.
        @param parent Qt parent."""
        super(TestObject, self).__init__(parent)
        self._data = {}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        """Gets an item from self._data"""
        if key in self._data.keys():
            return self._data[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        """Sets the value for key."""
        self._data[key] = value

###############################################################################

class TestModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Creates a new instance of TestModel.
        @param parent Qt parent."""
        super(TestModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._objects = []
        for i in range(5):
            obj = TestObject(self)
            obj[i] = str(i)
            self._objects.append(obj)

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        """Returns the amount of datasets."""
        return len(self._objects)

    def columnCount(self):
        """Returns the amount of columns, which is 1."""
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        """Returns the data for the given model index"""
        if index.isValid():
            obj = self._objects[index.row()]
            if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                return str(obj)
            elif role == Qt.UserRole:
                return obj
        return None

###############################################################################

def testfunc(index):
    """Does something with index."""
    print "getting..."
    index.data(Qt.UserRole)
    print "never getting here :/"

###############################################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QListView()
    view.setModel(TestModel())
    view.clicked.connect(testfunc)
    view.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in PySide. It works fine with PyQt4.

Comment: Ok, got it: `__getitem__` needs to raise `IndexError()` when the key is invalid. Works now

Comment: Ah, interesting. I still don't see why, though. What is calling `__getitem__` on `TestObject`?

Comment: I can't tell. I figure it is called somewhere inside of PySide, since I don't call it myself explictly (at least in this reproducer)...so it  probably is a bug of some sort.

Comment: rowCount() should return 0 if parent is valid, otherwise you end up with an infinitely deep tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__getitem__` needs to raise `IndexError()` on invalid key

Answer (score 0):

It seems that PySide is trying to iterate over you objects (can't say why). Just as said in comment, you need to raise IndexError in `__getitem__` to stop this iteration inside of PySide.

Info about `__getitem__` and iteration over an object: https://stackoverflow.com/a/926645/812662