# Why does making a class iterable produce this output?

Tags: python, iterable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does defining **getitem** on a class make it iterable in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926574/why-does-defining-getitem-on-a-class-make-it-iterable-in-python)

```
class b:
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return k

cb = b()

for k in cb:
    print k
```

I get the output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
.....
```

Iterating over instance of class b, emits integers. Why is that?

(came across the above program when looking at [Why does defining __getitem__ on a class make it iterable in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926574/why-does-defining-getitem-on-a-class-make-it-iterable-in-python))

Comment: Why did you post an exact duplicate of a question you linked to and was already perfectly answered there?

Comment: @Rob In that post, i had some trouble figuring out as to why integers were being output

Comment: In hindsight, i should have looked at semantics of __getitem__ before posting this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the for-loop is implemented for objects that define `__getitem__` but not `__iter__` by passing successive indices to the object's `__getitem__` method. See [the effbot](http://effbot.org/zone/python-for-statement.htm). (What really happens under the covers IIUC is a bit more complicated: if the object doesn't provide `__iter__`, then `iter` is called on the object, and the iterator that `iter` returns does the calling of the underlying object's `__getitem__`.)