# Exception Handling in Loops in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I try to capture multiple IndexErrors in the same loop, yet I can only capture the first one. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926574/why-does-defining-getitem-on-a-class-make-it-iterable-in-python) question might be related to my question, yet I cannot understand it. If it helps, I am using Enthought Canopy 1.6.2 on Windows 10 and Python 2.7.13.

```py
import numpy as np

some_array=np.zeros(10)
some_set=[2,4,15,19]
for sense in some_set:
    try:
        some_array[sense]=1
    except IndexError:
        some_set.remove(sense)
        print some_set, "sense"
```

The output I receive is:

> [2, 4, 19] sense

While I want an output of the form

> [2, 4, 19] sense
>
> [2, 4] sense

Comment: You're modifying the set while iterating over it. That never ends up with anything good.

Comment: Should I delete the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue comes forth from the fact that you are modifying the array you are looping through. In python a `for x in y:` is basically the same as `for i in range(len(y)): x = y[i]`.

The issue is that you are at index 2 in your loop, which yields the element `15`. You then catch the error and remove `15` from the array. All good. However, now the array you are looping through is `[2, 4, 19]` and you just ended an iteration, letting Python know to see what the element is at index 3. There is no index 3 anymore, so Python will terminate the loop.

To stop your problem from occurring, simply loop over a copy of the array, so that you are not altering the array you are also checking, using `.copy()` or `[:]`.

```
import numpy as np
some_array=np.zeros(10)
some_set=[2,4,15,19]
for sense in some_set[:]:  # This line was changed to use [:]
    try:
        some_array[sense]=1
    except IndexError:
        some_set.remove(sense)
        print some_set, "sense"
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole loop doesn't stop.

Try to add a number like 21 to the end of your set, and I think you'll see what's happening.

Python is reading index 0 of the loop, then 1, then 2, etc. So it reads 2 (index 0,) then 4 (index 1,) then 15 (index 2) and it deletes it. But then the list is [2, 4, 19, 21] and it reads index 3.

```
[2, 4, 19, 21] sense
[2, 4, 19] sense
```

As bereal mentions, you should avoid modifying a set when iterating over it.