# Is there a way to disable iteration for classes that define a __getitem__ method without putting constraints on the key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration, accessor

The class that acts as my starting point is as follows:

```
class Test:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        global frame
        frame = inspect.currentframe()
        if key > 9:
            raise KeyError
        return key
```

My thought was to use `frame.f_back` to discover that an iterator was automatically created for an instance as in the following example:

```
for x in Test():
    x
```

After running both of these and looking at `frame.f_back`, it was not obvious if `__getitem__` can get enough information to detect if it is being called from whatever "iterator" that is interacting with it. The easiest solution would be to make the container start at one instead of zero to access its contents or maybe even to force wrapping the key in a list before passing it to the function as shown here:

```
>>> class Test:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if not isinstance(key, list):
            raise TypeError
        if len(key) != 1:
            raise ValueError
        key = key.pop()
        if not isinstance(key, int):
            raise TypeError
        if not 0 <= key < 10:
            raise KeyError
        return key


>>> for x in Test():
    x


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#42>", line 1, in <module>
    for x in Test():
  File "<pyshell#39>", line 4, in __getitem__
    raise TypeError
TypeError
>>> Test()[[5]]
5
>>>
```

Is there a way that `__getitem__` can know that it is being used automatically as an iterator and raise an exception to prevent such usage?

**Related:** [Why does defining __getitem__ on a class make it iterable in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/926574/216356)

Comment: This question provides [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as required and is part of a larger problem. This is not part of a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/148746).

Comment: If your question is part of a larger problem, it's very possible that it *is* an XY problem.  Does the problem very specifically requires you to implement the limitation on `__getitem__`? Having that extra bit of insight can be helpful.  Regardless, does the question boil down to not allowing the object to iterate?

Comment: @r.ook Yes, it _could_ be an XY problem but has been determined to _not_ be an XY problem. The code is part of a class that is designed for teaching about arrays as one might work with them in C. The class defines `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, and no `__len__`. Yes, the object should not be iterable. The two methods could be renamed to `get_value` and `set_value`, but my hope was to keep the usual array syntax.

Comment: In that scenario, wouldn't a `def __iter__(self): raise TypeError('Object is not iterable')` suffice? `for x in foo` will return `iter(foo)` first, which raises the error.  But the `__getitem__` can still be called individually.

Comment: @r.ook Thank you! If you add that as an answer here, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is to stop the object from being an iterable, you can just force an error on `__iter__` method:

```
class Test:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key > 9:
            raise KeyError
        return key
    def __iter__(self):
        raise TypeError('Object is not iterable')
```

Test run:

```
>>> t = Test()
>>> for x in t:
    print(x)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#126>", line 1, in <module>
    for x in t:
  File "<pyshell#122>", line 7, in __iter__
    raise TypeError('Object is not iterable')
TypeError: Object is not iterable
```

But `__getitem__` will still work:

```
>>> t[0]
0
>>> t[1]
1
>>> t[10]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#129>", line 1, in <module>
    t[10]
  File "<pyshell#122>", line 4, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError
KeyError
```

Comment: Fun fact: There is also an link to answer included in the question.

Comment: Yes, I think OP was too pigeon-holed in implementing a fix in `__getitem__` so that answer unfortunately didn't pop out to them.

Comment: @r.ook You are right. It was not intuitive to me to define an "unrelated" method and raise an exception there. The answer is obvious now, but many things are in hindsight.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is implementing both `__getitem__` and `__iter__` methods.
When trying to acces individual elements `__getitem__` will be triggered, when trying to iterate `__iter__` will be called and an exception raised.

```
class Test():
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return k

    def __iter__(self):
        raise TypeError
```

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate that this is a fairly old thread, but I don't believe these answers to be quite sufficient. In particular if we define `__iter__` as

```py
class MyClass:
    ...
    def __iter__(self):
        raise TypeError
    ...
```

then Python now thinks that `isinstance(myobj, collections.abc.Iterable)` is `True` (since it looks for an `__iter__` method, [source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html?highlight=collections#collections.abc.Iterable)), when it explicitly isn't!

The right solution (found [here](https://discuss.python.org/t/deprecate-old-style-iteration-protocol/17863/2)) is actually to do the following:

```py
class MyClass:
    ...
    __iter__ = None
    ...
```