# Built in iter() function and for statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to understand how the `for x in y` statement works in python.  I found the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for.  It says that the expression `y` is evaluated once and must yield an iterable object.

The following code prints the numbers 1,2,3,4,5 even though my class does not implement `__iter__` (which is my understanding of being an iterable).

```py
class myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = [1,2,3,4,5]
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        return self.x[index]
m = myclass()
for i in m:
    print(i)
```

I know that there is a built-in method `iter()` that returns an iterator for a sequence object using its `.__getitem__()` function and a counter that starts at 0.

My guess is that python is calling the `iter()` function on the expression `y` in the `for x in y` statement.  So it is converting my object that implements `.__getitem__` into an iterator, and when my object raises a `IndexError` exception during the `.__getitem__` call, the iterator turns this into a `StopIteration` exception, and the for loop ends.

Is this correct?  Right or wrong, is this explained in the documentation somewhere, or do I need to go look inside the source code of the implementation?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/iterator.html

Comment: `__getitem__()` with sequential indexes, terminated by `IndexError`, was the original version of Python's iterator protocol, dating back to the Python 1.x days. Apparently, it's still supported, for backward compatibility.  But yes, the `iter()` function is exactly equivalent to what a `for` loop does with its sequence object.

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/

Comment: @RichieV: The fact that lists have an `__iter__` method is actually completely irrelevant. This code would behave the same if lists did not have an `__iter__`.

Comment: Right -- this would be a way of making lists iterable if they weren't already.

Comment: @jasonharper - interesting. I was surprised this work. I think it would be worth making that the answer.

Comment: @Barmar It would appear from reading the link you posted that the "PyObject_GetIter()" function is responsible for both the built-in `iter` function and the behavior of the for loop.  That seems like a pretty conclusive answer to my question.

Comment: @RichieV: `iter` falls back to indexing with sequential integer indices if an object has no `__iter__`.

Comment: @RichieV - the iterator doesn't see any of the internal attribues such as the list in `self.x` (suppose the object had 2 lists). It just blindly thows 0, 1, 2, etc... at `__getitem__` until it fails.

Comment: Got it, I see "An object can be iterated over with for if it implements __iter__() or __getitem__()." From Barmar's reference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does defining \_\_getitem\_\_ on a class make it iterable in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926574/why-does-defining-getitem-on-a-class-make-it-iterable-in-python)

Comment: @mkrieger1 That question explains why `__getitem__` makes a class iterable.  My question was whether the way `y` in `for x in y` is evaluated into an iterator was the same as how the built-in function `iter(y)` constructs an iterator from `y`.  A comment above provides a reference where it is explained that the implementation of both of these things are the same.  The code I posted was just an example that helped motivate the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to PEP 234, which was helpfully linked in the comments above,

> `iter(obj)` calls `PyObject_GetIter(obj)`.

It has the following to say about for loops:

> The Python bytecode generated for for loops is changed to use new opcodes, `GET_ITER` and `FOR_ITER`, that use the iterator protocol rather than the sequence protocol to get the next value for the loop variable. This makes it possible to use a for loop to loop over non-sequence objects that support the tp_iter slot. Other places where the interpreter loops over the values of a sequence should also be changed to use iterators.

Finally, https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-GET_ITER explains that `GET_ITER` is equivalent to calling `iter`.

Putting this together, it seems that the for loop behaves the same as the built-in `iter` function.

Answer (score 0):

Happy Pythoning.

**getitem** was the only method before Python 2.2 version to iterate loops on iterators. In Pyhton 2.2 version **iter** method was introduced. In **getitem** method, index is automatically passed as 0 ie 0 index and increase by 1 every time loop runs iterates. We exit from loop once IndexError raises. To have the backward compatibility **getitem** method is still not deprecated (Till Python version 3.8.5). So now firstly loop searches **iter** method is searched in iterable and if this method is not present then **getitem** method is searched. So as long back Python 2.2 came, so today developers prefer to use **iter** and **next** methods, which gives a clear cut understanding about iterable and iterator.

You can take one more example of **getitem** along with your example to understand iterator and iterable as follows.

```
class myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        return index
m = myclass()
for i in m:
    print(i)
```

Above code will create an infinite loop because first index value will be 0 then 1 then 2 and so on and no error will be raised.

Output of above code:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
.
.
.
.
```

Thanks for sharing the question.