# how to customize implementation of the for in statement

Tags: python

When we implement our own obj in python which support for i in obj statement, what magic method we need to create?

Is there a link to the official document that I can check?

During my reading of some other's source code, I found there's a `__getitem__` method, it has a signatue of `__getitem__(slef, index)`, then when we instantiate an object of this class, and call

```
for i in obj:
   print(i)
```

what method would python try to find and pass what argument?

Comment: Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926574/why-does-defining-getitem-on-a-class-make-it-iterable-in-python ?

Comment: The code passes ints starting at 0, until your code (in getitem) raises an IndexError

Comment: thanks, @zaro.  I only know that __iter__  is the magic method for for in statement, now I get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a class iterable by implementing

- `__getitem`, it'll receive ints starting at 0, your code needs to raise a `IndexError` to stop it

  ```
  class Foo:
      def __getitem__(self, item):
          if isinstance(item, int) and item > 10:
              raise IndexError
          return item * 2
  ```
- `__iter__` and `__next__`

  ```py
  class Foo:

      def __init__(self):
          self.counter = 0

      def __iter__(self):
          return self

      def __next__(self):
          if self.counter > 10:
              raise StopIteration
          result = self.counter * 2
          self.counter += 1
          return result
  ```

---

Both leads to same output

```
for i in Foo():
    print(i)

0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
```