# How does a Python for loop with iterable work?

Tags: python, for-loop, iterable

I'm confused by Python's `for` loop syntax. Consider a code example like:

```
for party in feed.entry:
    print(party.location.address.text)
```

What does `for party in feed.entry` actually mean, given that `feed.entry` is an *iterable*? Step by step, what happens when the loop runs?

---

<sub>This question is primarily about how the loop syntax is implemented, on a technical level. For a beginner-level explanation of the syntax, see [Understanding for loops in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257862).</sub>

<sub>To close debugging questions with the common problem wherein OP has incorrectly attempted `y[x]` within a loop like `for x in y:`, use [Why do I get an IndexError (or TypeError, or just wrong results) from "ar[i]" inside "for i in ar"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51919448).</sub>

Comment: I think you need a simple tutorial: http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/python-scripting-tutorial/loops-tutorial.php

Comment: The language feature that's new to you is an [**iterable** is an object capable of returning its members one at a time](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable). See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/9884259/202229 . Where Python differs from C++ is you don't need to know exactly what type of object `feed.entry` or set up all the clunky C++ scaffolding ([Drakosha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1292205/202229)) before using it. You simply say `for x in <iterable>`

Answer (score 25):

feed.entry is property of feed and it's value is (if it's not, this code will fail) object implementing iteration protocol (array, for example) and has **iter** method, which returns iterator object

Iterator has next() method, returning next element or raising exception, so python for loop is actually:

```
iterator = feed.entry.__iter__()
while True:
    try:
        party = iterator.next()
    except StopIteration:
        # StopIteration exception is raised after last element
        break

    # loop code
    print party.location.address.text
```

Comment: +1, as giving equivalent lower-level code is often the best explanation; wish I could give only +0.9 since the first line should be `iter(feed.entry)` (most of the time when you're calling a special method directly rather than through a builtin you're doing it wrong, though there are exceptions to this;-).

Comment: Note that in Python 3 the magic `next` method is now called `__next__`. And you can invoke it using the [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) built-in function.

Answer (score 6):

feed.entry is something that allows iteration, and contains objects of some type. This is roughly similar to c++:

```
for (feed::iterator party = feed.entry.begin(); party != feed.entry.end(); ++party) {
   cout << (*party).location.address.text;
}
```

Comment: If i remember correctly, it's how old (pre 2.0) python worked (using length(), [] and counter)

Answer (score 3):

Formally a [`for` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) in Python always operates on an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) -- an object which can provide an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) over its items. The `for` statement successively fetches the [`next` element from the iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next), assigns it to the target name(s) and runs the suite ("body") with that.

```
#   |name|   |iterable|
for party in feed.entry:
    # body...
    print(party.location.address.text)
```

In the example, `feed.entry` is the iterable, `party` is the target name and `print ...` is the suite. The iterator is automatically requested by the `for` statement, and holds the iteration state - e.g. the index of the next element if the iterable is a list.

---

If you are coming from C++, a classical [`for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) represents [*external iteration*](https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2013/01/13/iteration-inside-and-out/): the iteration state `i` is kept outside of the iterable. This corresponds to Python's `while` loop:

```
# for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
i = 0
while i < 10:
    i += 1
    # access the state of an iterable here
```

The newer [`for (auto party : entry)` range loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) represents *internal iteration*: the iteration state is kept by a separate iterator. This corresponds to Python's `for` loop. However, the iterable/iterator protocol differs notably: Python's `for` uses `iter(iterable)` to get an iterator, which should support `next(iterator)` - either returning an element or raising `StopIteration`.

Written in Python, the [definition of the `for` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) corresponds to this:

```
# for party in feed.entry:
__iterator = iter(feed.entry)  # iterator -- not visible in containing scope
__iterating = True             # graceful exit to enter `else` clause
while __iterating:
    try:                          # attempt to...
        item = next(__iterator)   # ... get the next item
    except StopIteration:         # ... or stop
        __iterating = False       #     with a graceful exit
    else:
        party = item
        <suite>                # run the body with names bound
else:                          # entered in a graceful exit only
    <else suite>
```

(Note that the entire block from `__iterating = True` to `__iterating = False` is not "visible" to the containing scope. Implementations use various optimisations, such as CPython allowing [builtin iterators to return a C `NULL` instead of raising a Python `StopIteration`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_iternext).)

The `for` statement just defines *how* iterable and iterator are used. If you are mostly familiar with external iteration, it helps looking at iterable and iterator as well.

---

The `iter(iterable)` call has [multiple ways to derive an iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) - this is as if `iter` were overloaded for various structural types.

- If `type(iterable).__iter__` is defined, it is called as a method and the result is used as the iterator.
- If `type(iterable).__getitem__` is defined, it is wrapped by a generic iterator type that returns `iterable[0]`, `iterable[1]`, ... and raises `StopIteration` if `IndexError` is raised when indexing.

Either way, `iter` returns an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter) or raises `TypeError`. An iterator is *any* type that defines `__iter__` (for reusability) and `__next__` (for the actual iteration). In general, iterators are objects that may hold state to compute the `__next__` item. For example, a list iterator corresponds to this object:

```
class ListIterator:
    """Python equivalent of ``iter(:list)``"""
    # iterator holds iteration state - e.g. iterable and current index
    def __init__(self, iterable: list):
        self.iterable = iterable
        self.index = 0

    # __next__ fetches item and advances iteration state - e.g. index += 1
    def __next__(self):
        # attempt to produce an item
        try:
            item = self.iterable[self.index]
        except IndexError:  # translate indexing protocol to iteration protocol
            raise StopIteration
        # update iteration state
        self.index += 1
        return item

    # iterators can be iterated on in ``for`` statements etc.
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
```

(Note that one would idiomatically write such an object as a [generator function](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr).)

Indexing a list or incrementing some pointer is only a very basic example of the iterable/iterator protocol. For example, an iterator could be stateless and use `random.random()` in `__next__` to produce an infinite stream of random numbers. Iterators can also hold state of external information, and iteratively traverse a file system, for example.

Answer (score 2):

**party** simply iterates over the *iterable* **feed.entry**

Take a look at [Dive into Python](https://linux.die.net/diveintopython/html/file_handling/for_loops.html) explainations.

Comment: Not necessarily a list. Better to call it an iterable.

Comment: Yes indeed. But it seemed to be a beginner question. I wanted to keep the response simple.

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: dead link fixed

Answer (score 1):

In Python, *for* bucles aren't like the C/C++ ones, they're most like PHP's *foreach*. What you do isn't iterate like in a *while* with "(initialization; condition; increment)", it simply iterates over each element in a list (strings are ITERABLE like lists).

For example:

```
for number in range(5):
    print number
```

will output

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: strings are NOT lists.  Strings are iterables, and so are lists, but strings and lists are certainly two distinct types in Python.

Comment: Well, in many languages strings are arrays of characters, and in Python its behavior is very similar when iterating... edit...

Comment: Yes, strings and lists are very similar *when iterating* but importantly different in many other cases.  For instance, you cannot modify a string.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to provide a more generic explanation for people new to this.

Syntactically, the `for` loop looks like...

```
for <name to be assigned to> in <some sequence>:

    <block of code, optionally referencing the name>
```

The interpreter runs the block once for each item in the sequence (anything that can iterated over). Each time it runs the block, it first assigns the next object in the sequence to the name, which can be any valid variable name.

Doing `for each in (1, 2, 3): print(each)` is [more or less] the same as doing...

```
i = 0
sequence = (1, 2, 3)
while True:
    try:
        each = sequence[i]
        print(each)
        i += 1
    except IndexError: pass
```

You can also unpack arguments in the assignment part. In the same way that you can do stuff like...

```
a, b = 1, 2
```

...you can also do stuff like...

```
for a, b in [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]: print(a + b)
```

...which prints...

```
3
7
11
```

Answer (score -1):

Python's `for` loop works with `iterators`, which must implement the `iterator` protocol.  For more details see:

- [Build a Basic Python Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator/24377#24377)