# Formal interpretation of `in` in Python's `for` loops

Tags: python, for-loop

I know that the `in` operator can be used in Python as a short-hand of the following (generally speaking, not considering any hidden equality issues or anything):

```
for item in list1:
    if item == thingToCheck:
        return True
return False
```

However, I was wondering about the technical meaning of `in`  in the actual `for item in list1` line- obviously there is another meaning to `in`, since Python wouldn't generate every single possible value of `item` and see if `item in list1`.  On a related note, are Python `for` loops ever made without `in`?

Comment: Related: [how-does-python-for-loop-work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292189/how-does-python-for-loop-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`in` calls the `__contains__` method (of `list` in this case)

For `list` and `tuple` this is linear search

For `dict` and `set` it uses a hash

When used in a for loop, `in` just means take the next item from the iterable until it runs out.

You can imagine it's something like this

```
it = iter(list1)
while True:
    try:
        item = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    if item == thingToCheck:
        return True
return False
```

Comment: Good explanation.  I'd still really like to know about `for` loops without `in` in them.  So can I presume that Python does something like "overriding" the `in` keyword to fit these very different uses?

Comment: @Tangmeister: I don't believe you'll find a `for` loop without using `in`. Note that when used in a `for` loop line, the `in` doesn't mean the same thing as when it's used in an expression.

Comment: Yes, some keywords have different meanings depending on their context. This is partly to avoid having too many keywords

Answer (score 2):

No, you won't find a `for` loop without `in`, because it is syntactically necessary, see [Python language reference](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement). As Greg pointed out, the fact, that the same keyword is used, does not mean, that the internal processing is similar let alone identical. Similar is the never-dying discussion concerning programming languages, where `=` has the two roles of assignment and as comparison operator. Programming languages are designed for readability and to abstract from what is actually happening, and the abstraction increases with the level of the language.