# learning how to use guarding on optional unwrapping

Tags: swift

I have been trying to write a simple function for adding two variables.

```
func add(X: Int?, Y: Int?) -> Int? {
    guard let X != nil, Y != nil else
    { return nil }
    return X + Y
}
```

I keep getting the following 2 error messages:

> "Pattern matching in a condition requires the 'case' keyword"

and

> "Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer"

Can someone help me fix this code?

Comment: You should be reading the documentation on optional binding: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID333

Comment: Or a summary here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24128860/how-is-optional-binding-used-in-swift

Answer (score 3):

You want your `guard` to be:

```
guard let X = X, let Y = Y else {
    return nil
}
```

When using `guard let` you need an assignment, not a condition. And each variable needs its own `let`.

Comment: don't forget about the naming conventions `guard let x = x, let y = y else {` and `func add(x: Int?, y: Int?) -> Int? {`

Comment: @LeoDabus Yeah. I just went with the OP's code. I get tired of repeating myself over and over :)