# Programming a math function in python

Tags: python

This is what I have to program:

```
sen(x) = (x/1!) - (x^3/3!) + (x^5/5!) - (x^7/7!) + ...
```

So far I have this:

```
def seno(x, n):
    for i in range(1, n+1, 2):
        result = (x**i/math.factorial(i))
        result1 = (x**i/math.factorial(i))
        result2 = (x**i/math.factorial(i))
        result3 = (x**i/math.factorial(i))
    return math.sin(result-result1 + result2 - result3)
```

The thing I can’t understand is how to actually change the `i` value for each result.

Another thing is I can’t use any non-built-in function. So no imports except for the math.

EDIT: Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: You seem to be trying to compute the sine using the taylor expansion manually.  Why are you using `math.sin()` on the result then?  Your assignments to the variables `result*` all have the same right-hand side, so they will all end up with the same value.

Comment: Thought `math.sin()` would be required.

Comment: Did you actually try running it?  From looking at the code, I'd expect the function to always return 0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Python for loop work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292189/how-does-python-for-loop-work)

Comment: Yes i know that it will return 0.

Comment: I think you first need to get a clear understanding of what you are trying to achieve.  From the requirement that you can only import functions from `math`, I infer that this is homework for some course you are taking (since this requirement wouldn't make sense in any other context).  The aim _seems_ to be to approximate the sine with a Taylor series.  The function `math.sin()` already does this for you (or actually asks your computer's hardware to do it).  If you want to write a software implementation of the Taylor approximation, you shouldn't call `math.sin()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're doing a [Taylor Series approximation of Sine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Approximation_and_convergence).

You probably shouldn't declare separate `result1`, `result2`, etc. Instead, you compute each value in a loop, and accumulate it in a single `result` variable.

```
def seno(x,n):
    result = 0
    sign = 1 # Sign starts out positive
    for i in range(1, n+1, 2):
        result += x**i/math.factorial(i)
        sign *= -1 # use negative sign on odd terms
    return result
```

Note that you don't actually call `math.sin` on the result. The whole point of using a Taylor Series approximation is to *estimate* the value of `math.sin(x)` without actually calling that function.

You can optimize this loop a bit more. You can do a [strength reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_reduction) on `math.factorial` by accumulating the answer rather than recomputing the whole factorial value on each iteration. You can also do a similar strength reduction on the `x**i` term, and roll the sign-switching logic into the update logic for `exp` as well.

```
def seno(x,n):
    result = 0.0
    fact = 1.0   # start with '1!'
    exp = x      # start with 'x¹'
    xx = x*x     # xx = x²
    for i in range(1, n+1, 2):
        result += exp / fact
        exp *= -xx  # update exponential term to 'xⁱ', and swap sign
        fact *= (i+1) * (i+2) # update factorial term to '(i+2)!'
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `for` loop incorrectly. Each iteration will compute one term of the series; you need to accumulate those values rather than trying to set 4 results at a time.

```
def seno(x, n):
    sign = 1
    result = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1, 2):
        term = x**i/math.factorial(i)
        result += sign * term
        sign *= -1  # Alternate the sign of the term
    return result
```

Comment: @SvenMarnach: `i` is always odd in this loop, so I don't think your suggestion would work.