# Why is the iterator in for loop a string and not an integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the code I wrote:

```
a = "5,3,1"
print (type(a))
b = []
b = a.split(",")
print (type(b))
print (b)
for i in b:
    if (int(i) % 5 == 0):
        print (i) 

print (type(i))
```

In the for loop, I was expecting the variable `i` to be an integer type. But turns out that it is a string. How does this make sense?

**Output**

```
<class 'str'>                                                                                                                                                                      
<class 'list'>                                                                                                                                                                     
['5', '3', '1']                                                                                                                                                                    
5                                                                                                                                                                                  
<class 'str'>
```

How can we use a string as an iterator to loop through the list items in a list?
Further if I remove the `int` in the line `if (int(i) % 5 == 0):`, I get this error:
`TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`
I'm unable to understand how this works

Comment: Why do you expect it to be an `int`? `b == a.split()` and `str.split` always returns a list of strings, so of course when you iterate over a list of strings, the items are strings... Note, `i` **is not an iterator** in Python terminology. `i` is simply a variable that gets assigned the next item in the iterator returned by the iterable you are iterating over

Comment: Excuse my poor knowledge. `For` loops normally have iterators in other languages... Looks like it is different in python

Comment: [This answer in particular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57816761/5014455) which goes into detail and addresses confusions that may come from other languages

Comment: Python does use iterator-based for-loops.  But `i` is not an iterator, it is merely a variable that gets assigned *the next item from the iterator* on each iteration. What language did you have in mind? *why* did you expect `i` to be an `int`? What ints were you expecting?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for your reference. It's now clear to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b` is a list of strings, correct? This is `b`:

```
['5', '3', '1']
```

So when you start iterating through `b`, each value of `i` will be a string because strings are all there is in `b`. 
When you say `int(i)` in your `if` statement, you are **not** changing `i` to an integer. You are only getting the integer value of `i`.

If you want `b` to be a list of integers instead of a list of strings, use this instead:

```
b = [int(num) for num in a.split(",")]
```

Output:

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'list'>
[5, 3, 1]
5
<class 'int'>
```

You can see that `i` is now an integer.

Comment: I missed to see that the elements of list b are still strings.... Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

When you split a string into **b**, you get a list of strings, `["5", "3", "1"]`. When you iterate through **b**, your loop variable, **i** is assigned to each value in the list, and each value is a string. You can turn the value in **i** into an integer with `int(i)`, but unless you manually convert the value, it remains a string. This is why you cannot use `if i % 5`, because `string % int` is not defined in Python.