# Python for loop ineration variable not an integer

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration

I am working on a bot that would work with ical files and the events inside them. The way it works is that the ical file is read in to a variable `data` that is then parsed by the ics library and converted in to a list of events. The variable `eventlist` is a `<class 'list'>` containing elements of the type: `<class 'ics.event.Event'>`

```
from ics import Calendar
import time
from datetime import datetime

#open the ical file for processing
with open("D:\\Downloads\\d210107c532744427a.ics", 'r') as file:
     data = file.read()
c = Calendar(data)
eventlist = list(c.events) #create a list of all the events
```

However, when I try to iterate over `eventlist` using a `for` loop the iterator is not an integer rather it becomes a `<class 'ics.event.Event'>` example below:

```
for x in eventlist:
    print(type(x))
```

Output of the above code is:

```
<class 'ics.event.Event'>
<class 'ics.event.Event'>
<class 'ics.event.Event'>
...
```

This is a problem because when trying to access an element from `eventlist` using `eventlist[x]` an error occurs since x need to be an integer.

Is there any way to suppress this behavior and make the for loop return integers for the iterator?

Edit 1: I understood that this is how for loops are supposed to behave in Python, however I would also like to know if there is a way to get the position if the current `x` in the list as an integer?

Comment: ``x`` is *already* "an element from ``eventlist``". Just use ``x`` instead of ``eventlist[x]``.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does a Python for loop with iterable work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292189/how-does-a-python-for-loop-with-iterable-work)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes it does, that was an oversight from my side, I forgot how for loops work in python, thanks.

Comment: `for` loops **always** iterate *over the elements of an iterable*. There is no way to "suppress" that behavior, and there is no good reason to want to. The are various built-in functions, e.g. `enumerate` that provide various iterators that you may find useful.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I would like to get the position of some elements depending on a check, how would that be possible with this approach?

Comment: As an aside, "iterator" in Python does not mean the loop variable. An iterator is an object returned from an iterable's `__iter__` method, the iterator implements a `__next__` method (along with an `__iter__` method itself that simply returns `self`)

Comment: @Coder_fox `for index, event in enumerate(eventlist): ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop you are using :

```
for x in eventlist:
    print(type(x))
```

defines that x is an eventlist so what you do is:

```
for x in eventlist:
    print(x) #to print each event
```