# Why is this list being printed out 3 times instead of one? Why is my nested for loop not working as expected?

Tags: python

I have a 2d array where I'm trying to iterate through the thing and print ouf every element. For loops in Python are annoying/confusing because you don't have the expressability as you do in C++ with being able to set conditions/increments.

Anyways, when I try to print out the contents of this array, it prints out the contents of the array 3 times instead of just once.

```
twoDarray = [[10, 15, 20], [25, 30, 35], [45, 50, 60]]
for i in twoDarray:
    for num in twoDarray:
        print(num)
```

Why is my nested for loop not working as expected?

Comment: You are looping through the whole array again in the inner loop instead of looping through the row.

Comment: Try `for num in twoDarray:` --> `for num in i:`

Comment: but loop variables in python don't mean anything right? i could acll the two loop variables whatever i want. in c++ you have to define them like `int i =0` and `int j=0`. why does it matter if i call the second for loop variable `num`. also big question: why am i am taking the `num` variable and using that to iterate through `i`? im confused

Comment: In your own words: when you do `for i in twoDarray:`, what do you think will be the value of `i` the first time through the loop? The second time? The third? Why? When you try using a debugger or `print` statements to test that, does it work as you expect? Where you have `for num in twoDarray:`, same question. Now: what *should* the value of `num` be the first time through the inner loop? Where do you expect that value to come from? Therefore, according to your understanding of how the `for` loop works, how should you write the loop? In particular, what should go after `in`?

Comment: In your code ``twoDarray`` is not the loop variable, it is the iterable.

Comment: "why does it matter if i call the second for loop variable num" It doesn't matter, and nobody suggested that it matters. You were told to change your existing code, `for num in twoDarray:`, to `for num in i:`. What part is actually changing there? Hint: not `num`.

Comment: (The names don't mean anything in C++, either, and you could perfectly well write `for (int num=0; ...)`.

Comment: Might be relevant for understanding: [How does a Python for loop with iterable work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292189/how-does-a-python-for-loop-with-iterable-work)

Comment: Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Your opinion about Python as it compares to C++ is off topic and does not help answer the question.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel so im trying to think. for the outer for loop, you are accessing the inner 3 small arrays. okay, in this case what is the second for loop doing? i guess my question is when you said 'where you have `for num in twoDarray`:, what should the value of be the first time through the inner loop'. i dont know the answer to this question. what is the value the first time through the inner loop when i wrote `for num in twoDarray`?

Comment: "for the outer for loop, you are accessing the inner 3 small arrays. okay, in this case what is the second for loop doing? " Wrong question. What do you **want it** to do? You want it to access the individual integers that are in one of the small lists (we don't call them arrays!), right? Okay, so, **because** you used the outer `for` loop to "access the inner 3 small [lists]", and **because** you wrote `for i`, that means that `i` currently **is** one of the small lists.

Comment: So in the inner loop, you have a "small list" named `i`, and you want to access the individual elements of `i`. You write that `for` loop the same way you would write any other `for` loop: by **deciding** a name to use for the individual elements (you previously chose `num`; let's stick with that) on the left, and **specifying** where the elements come from on the right. Thus: `for num in i:`.

Comment: This process is, I would argue, [much easier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383250/why-should-i-use-foreach-instead-of-for-int-i-0-ilength-i-in-loops/4383321#4383321) to understand than C++'s. C++ has warped your thinking to the contrary.

Comment: oh, so on the outer loop, i 'takes the place' of a sub list right? so you have to do `for j in i` to be able to print all of the elements of the inner array right?

Answer (score 3):

You are iterating through the same list twice. Note that your `in` variables are `twoDarray` in both loops.

It should be something like:

```py
twoDarray = [[10, 15, 20], [25, 30, 35], [45, 50, 60]]
for line in twoDarray:
    for num in line:
        print(num)
```

Comment: why is the second in variable is line? why am i using the in variable from the outer loop for in variable in the inner loop?

Comment: "why is the second in variable is line?" Because this version says `for line in twoDarray:`. "why am i using the in variable from the outer loop for in variable in the inner loop?" The reason that you match up `line` like this is because the outer loop makes `line` a name for each of the rows in turn (by getting those values from the overall structure), and in the inner loop, you want to get values from the rows.

Comment: Python's syntax here means **exactly what it means in English**, just with some words omitted as shorthand. `for line in twoDarray:` exactly means "do the following, `for` each thing, which will be called `line` in the task description below, that is found `in` the `twoDarray`".

Answer (score 0):

Both loops iterating the same object...

```
for i in twoDarray:
    for num in i:
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i is also iterating twoDarray and num is also iterating twoDarray. That means i values will be the inner lists and num values will also be inner lists. You've to iterate the inner list in the 2nd loop. Change `for num in twoDarray` to `for num in i`. Now your num values will be the elements of the inner list (your desired output). Your code:

```
twoDarray = [[10, 15, 20], [25, 30, 35], [45, 50, 60]]
for i in twoDarray:
    for num in i:
        print(num)
```