# How can I restart a for loop in python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I was performing a code in python using for loop. But I want to restart the loop. How can I do this in for loop?

```
a=[some list]
z=len(a)
for i in range(z):
    if....:
        do something
    else:
        do some changes in "a"
        restart the loop from the beginning with i=0
```

How can I get there?

I don't have a clue actually on how to do this. I am very new to this.

Comment: Can you give some real, working code that's a bit closer to what you want?  What kind of condition is in that `if....`?  Could you put that condition in a `while` around the `for`?

Comment: You have to wrap the for-loop in another loop, e. g. `while flag:`. When you want to restart the for-loop, set `flag` to `True` and `break` out of the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use `while` loop instead of for loop

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
z = len(a)
i = 0

while i < z:
    if a[i] == 3:
        # do something
        i += 1
    else:
        # do some changes in "a"
        a[i] += 1
        i = 0
        continue
    i += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Using while loop the coding became easy.

Answer (score 0):

Surround the `for` loop with a `while` loop, and `break` from that loop when the "restart" condition is **not** met.

Breaking from multiple loops is tricky. It is especially tricky in this case, because we only want to break the `while` loop if **every** element of the `a` list is valid. The most straightforward way to do this is to start the `for` loop with the assumption that every element is valid, and set a flag when an invalid element is found.

As a side note, iterating in Python is normally done directly, not with indices. `for i in range(z)` [works by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292189) **creating a sequence** that the `i` values come from, and taking values **from that sequence**. If we want to use values that are in `a`, it is normally [much simpler and cleaner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383250) to just... do that.

Putting these ideas together, we might get something like:

```
a = [1, 2, 3] # some initial value
done = False
while not done:
    for i in a:
        done = True
        if condition(i):
            do_something()
        else:
            done = False # make sure the `while` loop repeats
            a = modify(a)
            break # breaks the `for` loop, to prevent handling other `i` values
    # If we get past the `for` loop and `done` is still `True`, that means
    # that every element was valid. The `while` loop will also exit.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance. I completed the code using while loop inside the for loop.