# Can't iterate over a list class in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a simple GUI front end for Plurk using pyplurk.

I have successfully got it to create the API connection, log in, and retrieve and display a list of friends. Now I'm trying to retrieve and display a list of Plurks.

pyplurk provides a GetNewPlurks function as follows:

```
  def GetNewPlurks(self, since):
    '''Get new plurks since the specified time.
    Args:
      since: [datetime.datetime] the timestamp criterion.
    Returns:
      A PlurkPostList object or None.
    '''
    offset = jsonizer.conv_datetime(since)
    status_code, result = self._CallAPI('/Polling/getPlurks', offset=offset)
    return None if status_code != 200 else \
           PlurkPostList(result['plurks'], result['plurk_users'].values())
```

As you can see this returns a PlurkPostList, which in turn is defined as follows:

```
class PlurkPostList:
  '''A list of plurks and the set of users that posted them.'''
  def __init__(self, plurk_json_list, user_json_list=[]):
    self._plurks = [PlurkPost(p) for p in plurk_json_list]
    self._users = [PlurkUser(u) for u in user_json_list]
  def __iter__(self):
    return self._plurks
  def GetUsers(self):
    return self._users
  def __eq__(self, other):
    if other.__class__ != PlurkPostList: return False
    if self._plurks != other._plurks: return False
    if self._users != other._users: return False
    return True
```

Now I expected to be able to do something like this:

```
api = plurk_api_urllib2.PlurkAPI(open('api.key').read().strip(), debug_level=1)
plurkproxy = PlurkProxy(api, json.loads)
user = plurkproxy.Login('my_user', 'my_pass')
ps = plurkproxy.GetNewPlurks(datetime.datetime(2009, 12, 12, 0, 0, 0))
print ps
for p in ps:
  print str(p)
```

When I run this, what I actually get is:

```
<plurk.PlurkPostList instance at 0x01E8D738>
```

from the "print ps", then:

```
    for p in ps:
TypeError: __iter__ returned non-iterator of type 'list'
```

I don't understand - surely a list *is* iterable? Where am I going wrong - how do I access the Plurks in the PlurkPostList?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem you are having, I always inherit `object` rather than nothing (i.e., `class PlurkPostList(object):`) so that I am using *new-style classes*.

Comment: ...and if you make `PlurkPostList` inherit from standard `list` you've got much less work to do.

Comment: @bobince, Not really. Inheriting list doesn't get you anything worth while.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you define your own `__iter__` method, you should realize that that `__iter__` method should return an *iterator*, not an *iterable*. You are returning a list, not an iterator to a list, so it fails. You can fix it by doing `return iter(self._plurks)`, for example.

If you wanted to do something a little more complex, like process each item in self._plurks as it's being iterated over, the usual trick is to make your `__iter__` method be a *generator*. That way, the returnvalue of the call to `__iter__` is the generator, which is an iterator:

```
def __iter__(self):
    for item in self._plurks:
        yield process(item)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. The definition of PlurkPostList class including the __iter__ function came directly from PyPlurk, so I blithely assumed it was OK and my own calling of it was deficient. I also hadn't cottoned on to the distinction between an interator and an iterable, so that was very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The `__iter__` method should return an object which implements the `next()` method.

A list does not have a `next()` method, but it has an `__iter__` method, which returns a `listiterator` object. The `listiterator` object has a `next()` method.

You should write:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self._plurks)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can also define the `next()` function and have `__iter__()` return self. See [Build a Basic Python Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator) for a nice example.

Comment: That would make multiple iterations over the same object cumbersome, however.

Comment: How would it be cumbersome? Am I missing something? I was under the impression that using generators, as you did, achieved the same as using next(). Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: When you make an object itself an iterator, it would have to maintain the state of the iteration. It would have to remember how often the `next` method had been called. When you use a generator the generator does that for you. When you implement an iterator you need to store that state somewhere on the iterator. When an object is its own iterator (like, for example, a `file` is) then the object  can only be iterated over once, and then has to be rewound (in the case of `file`, with the `seek` method, or by re-opening.)

Comment: ahh yes of course, you are right, you would need to maintain the state of the iterator yourself within the object.