# How to implement a minimal class that behaves like a sequence in Python?

Tags: python, sequence

I am looking for a sample minimal example of a class that mimics an immutable sequence in Python.

```
class MySequence()
    ...

a = MySequence()

len(a)

for i in a:
    pass

a[0]
```

What are the methods that must be implemented?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Build a Basic Python Iterator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator)

Comment: Check the Python documentation at http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question.  *Sequence*, *iterable* and *iterator* are three different things in Python.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you just want to be able to iterate over your sequence, you just need to implement the `__iter__` method returning an iterable. The easiest way to do this is to create a generator using the `yield` statement.

```
class MySequence(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        yield 1
        yield 2
        yield 3

for x in MySequence():
    print x # prints 1, then 2, then 3
```

However, this will not enable things like `MySequence()[1]`. For that you need to implement the `__getitem__` method, and should probably implement `__len__` as well.

```
class MySequence(object):
    def __len__(self):
        return 3

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == 0:
            return 1
        elif key == 1:
            return 2
        elif key == 2:
            return 3
        else:
            raise IndexError()

s = new MySequence()

for i in range(len(s)):
    print s[i] # prints 1, then 2, then 3

for x in s:
    print x # prints 1, then 2, then 3
```

Notice that I omitted `__iter__`. As long as `__getitem__` raises an `IndexError` when you try to get a value that's out-of-bounds, Python can use it for iteration. (I could still include `__iter__` if I wanted to be clearer, or wanted non-standard iteration behaviour.)

Comment: Are you sure that the last two lines are correct? They seem really strange to me. I supposed you wanted to write `print x` on the last line.

Answer (score 6):

Adding to @Jeremy's answer: A popular check that a value is a general sequence is to use `isinstance(value, collections.Sequence)`.

In order to make this true for your type it needs to inherit from [`collections.Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes), and this actually provides the iterator (and some other useful functions) as mixins, as long as you provide the `__len__` and `__getitem__` functions.

Borrowing from @Jeremy's answer, an example class would look like:

```
import collections
class MySequence(collections.Sequence):
    def __len__(self):
        return 3

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == 0:
            return 1
        elif key == 1:
            return 2
        elif key == 2:
            return 3
        else:
            raise IndexError()
```

Examples of usage:

```
s = MySequence()

for i in range(len(s)):
    print s[i] # prints 1, then 2, then 3

for x in s:
    print x # prints 1, then 2, then 3

print isinstance(s, collections.Sequence) # prints True

print 1 in s # prints True

print list(reversed(s)) # prints [3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: collections.Sequence has Been moved to collections.abc.Sequence more recent version of python.