# Why isn't there any special method for __max__ in python?

Tags: python

As the title asks. Python has a lot of special methods, `__add__`, `__len__`, `__contains__` et c. Why is there no `__max__` method that is called when doing max? Example code:

```
class A:
    def __max__():
        return 5

a = A()
max(a)
```

It seems like `range()` and other constructs could benefit from this. Am I missing some other effective way to do max?¨

**Addendum 1:**
As a trivial example, `max(range(1000000000))` takes a long time to run.

Comment: *"Why isn't"* questions are often hard to answer. Probably because nobody has identified a need for it yet, or because nobody got around to implementing it…

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45308212/is-there-a-way-to-return-a-custom-value-for-min-and-max-in-python

Comment: Can you provide a use case where `__max__` would make a considerable difference than using builtin `max`?

Answer (score 3):

I have no authoritative answer but I can offer my thoughts on the subject.

There are several built-in functions that have no corresponding special method. For example:

- `max`
- `min`
- `sum`
- `all`
- `any`

One thing they have in common is that they are reduce-like: They iterate over an iterable and "reduce" it to one value. The point here is that these are more of a building block.

For example you often wrap the iterable in a generator (or another comprehension, or transformation like `map` or `filter`) before applying them:

```
sum(abs(val) for val in iterable)       # sum of absolutes
any(val > 10 for val in iterable)       # is one value over 10
max(person.age for person in iterable)  # the oldest person
```

That means most of the time it wouldn't even call the `__max__` of the iterable but try to access it on the generator (which isn't implemented and cannot be implemented).

So there is simply not much of a benefit if these were implemented. And in the few cases when it makes sense to implement them it would be more obvious if you create a custom method (or property) because it highlights that it's a "shortcut" or that it's different from the "normal result".

For example these functions (`min`, etc.) have `O(n)` run-time, so if you can do better (for example if you have a sorted list you could access the `max` in `O(1)`) it might make sense to document that explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Some operations are not basic operations. Take `max` as an example, it is actually an operation based on comparison. In other words, when you get a **max** value, you are actually getting a **biggest** value.

So in this case, why should we implement a specified `max` function but not override the behave of comparison?

---

Think in another direction, what does `max` really mean? For example, when we execute `max(list)`, what are we doing?

I think we are actually checking `list`'s elements, and the `max` operation is not related to `list` itself at all.

`list` is just a container which is unnecessary in `max` operation. It is `list` or `set` or something else, it doesn't matter. What really useful is the elements inside this container.

So if we define a `__max__` action for `list`, we are actually doing another totally different operation. We are asking a container to give us advice about max value.

I think in this case, as it is a totally different operation, it should be a method of container instead of overriding built-in function's behave.