# iterate a list of objects based on a property

Tags: python, python-2.7, iteration

I know this is probably duplicate, but I couldn't find an answer that could solve my issue.

My class is defined as follows:

```
import time

class Destination(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.__idleness = time.time()
        # keeps track of the time value when object was created

    def get_idleness(self):
        now = time.time()
        return now - self.__idleness
```

What I want to do is to iterate a list of `Destination` objects based on the return value of `get_idleness()`, either with a for loop or with any function that uses an iterable object, for example `numpy.mean()` or built-in `max()` and `min()`.
I have tried adding the `__iter__()` as:

```
    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.get_idleness()
```

but when I tried this example, output was incorrect:

```
dests = []
for i in range(6):
    dests.append(Destination(name="wp%s" % i))

time.sleep(1)

print max(dests)

for d in dests:
    print "%s: %s" % (d.name, d.get_idleness())

# max(dests): wp1
# printing all the values shows that wp0 should be the correct return value
```

**EDIT**: I realize my question was unclear. My end goal would be to use the value returned by `self.get_idleness()` when iterating over a list of `Destination`s. That way, no matter the iterating method, I'd compare the Destinations based on the greater idleness value.

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: You have defined ``__iter__`` for type ``Destination``, but you call ``max`` on type ``List[Destination]``! It doesn't run what you think it does. In this case, ``max`` will use ``Destination.__lt__`` to find the largest item.

Comment: You mean you want the object to be directly interpreted as its idleness whenever it is used in an iterator? That's probably a bad idea. Why if you just want to loop a collection of destinations? Better use `map` when you need it: `max(map(Destination.get_idleness, some_destinations))`

Comment: Also your type is actually not orderable since it doesn't define any comparison method. The fact that `max(dests)` works is because you are using Python 2 which has [weird behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3270680/3767239) when it comes to ordering non-orderable objects. On Python 3 you would get an error.

Comment: Can you clarify the desired behaviour? Do you want ``max`` do find the "largest" ``Destination`` instance, **or**  do you want ``iter(:List[Destination])`` to yield the idleness?

Comment: Your clarification still is unclear. The iteration and comparison are two fundamentally separate things -- ``max`` just happens to do both. So is your goal iteration or comparison?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a bit confused. If you had a list of `Destination` objects and wanted to get, say, the max idleness among them, you could use:

```
dests = [] # Your list of Destination objects
for i in range(6):
    dests.append(Destination(name="wp%s" % i))

maxIdleness = max( [d.get_idleness() for d in dests] )
```

You want the `max` (or `min`, `mean` or whatever) from a list of destinations, so that's why you create a new list. You could also create the list beforehand and reuse it for several calculations which would be more efficient:

```
idlenessList = [d.get_idleness() for d in dests]
maxIdleness = max(idlenessList)
minIdleness = min(idlenessList)
```

If you're still insterested in having a class return a custom `min` or `max` value, the following question might help you:
[Is there a way to return a custom value for min and max in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45308212/is-there-a-way-to-return-a-custom-value-for-min-and-max-in-python)

---

Also note that there's an error in your code, you shouldn't use parentheses when accessing `__idleness` since it's an attribute and not a function:

```
    def get_idleness(self):
        now = time.time()
        return now - self.__idleness # not self.__idleness()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `min` or `max` object based on its `get_idleness` you can do so by specifying a `key` function:

```
max(dests, key=Destination.get_idleness)
```