Is [a,b][a>b] equivalent to min(b, a)?
I came upon a bit of third party Python code that read:
count = [remaining, readlen][remaining > readlen]

After staring at it for a bit, I have to ask: are there any cases where this construct is NOT equivalent to:
count = min(readlen, remaining)

i.e. are there there any functional differences between the two?

It's equivalent to (a > b) ? b : a which is also the classic min idiom in C. So I think it's the same, at least for integers.

min() is probably not defined in terms of operator > so overloading could change the result,  no?

@AllanWind it's just Python syntax that uses [ ] for lists and indexing

@gwr Yes, I know, I was talking about the >

Ah ok. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45308212/is-there-a-way-to-return-a-custom-value-for-min-and-max-in-python suggests min builtin will just call comparison on an iterator

It'll depend on the comparison methods. E.g. if only __lt__ existed and it always returned True (which would, admittedly, be a bit weird), the results will be opposite to each other.

Wow, what a way to write code that's going to be hard to understand later! The question of carefully understanding this code is a great one, but I hope no one takes this and starts using it.

@joanis it's a common construct in code golf, which serves as an anti-style guide

This seems to be the third-party code in question. Unless I'm mistaken, they are only working with ints, which makes the two constructs equivalent in this case.

@qwr Right, I guess code golf is never about legibility. Although [a,b][a<b] is 2 characters longer than min(a,b) so the latter should still be preferred, even in code golf. But I get the point.

@AllanWind It'll try __lt__ (<) first, then fall back to __gt__ (>) if __lt__ isn't defined.

The former compares remaining > readlen, while the latter compares remaining < readlen. Is this intended?

@qwr Taking the min of an *iterable is not relevant because OP's using the multi-argument form of min(), not the single-argument form.

Was switching the operands intentional? min returns the first minimum  object if both are equal. The odd construct does the same thing. By switching order, it seems to confuse the question to me.

To make them equivalent, we need to reverse the inequality sign (and the list) in the former. If we swap the operands in the latter, it will logically be the same, but there is still a difference in which of __gt__ and __lt__ is called. Though, the real question is whether OP wanted to know about these minor differences, or about a bigger picture.

@tdelaney "Was switching the operands intentional?" Not consciously.  But I'll leave the original unedited, since it underscores the subtlety that you point out.  Thanks!

@jonrsharpe can you put the example of overriding lt? it's useful to know. Otherwise I will write an answer

@joanis I should've said constructs like c,d which is shorter than python's ternary conditional https://stackoverflow.com/a/470376 appears not to short-circuit

Let's assume a == b. In this case, [a,b][a>b] returns a, since a>b evaluates to False, which is then cast to 0. But min(b, a) returns b (first argument).
This is not relevant for numbers, but it may matter if a and b are mutable objects, like lists:
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> b = [1, 2]
>>> c = [a, b][a>b]
>>> c is a
True
>>> c is b
False
>>> c.append(3)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b
[1, 2]

With lists, it matters which of two equal objects get picked.
Note that just switching the min arguments to min(a, b) would remove this difference.

Ah yes, the equality doesn't mean the same object case

For numbers of different types, it does actually have a noticeable difference. a = 1; b = 1.0 then [a, b][a > b] → 1 and min(b, a) → 1.0

It's now clear I should have written min(a, b) rather than min(b, a), but that wasn't so obvious when I asked the question!  Thank you!  (But yeah, this is not a code example to emulate!)

Both the constructs set count to the smaller of remaining and readlen so there will be no cases where they provide different results.

What if they're equal but not the same object?
