# How to make python object callable by numpy.array()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, inheritance

Some classes, such as `Series` in `pandas` produce instances that can be called by `numpy.array` and turned into numpy arrays.

How do I make instances of a class that I'm writing (which works with a few arrays at the core) be allowed to be passed as argument to `numpy.array` and converted to a numpy array?

(perhaps "callable" is not the right word)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It [looks like](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) one easy way is to make the object define an `__array__(self)` method that returns the array you want numpy.array to return.

You can also [make your object a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875911/how-to-implement-a-minimal-class-that-behaves-like-a-sequence-in-python): define `__iter__(self)` to return an iterator over all the items, `__getitem__(self, i)`, to return the ith element, and and `__len__(self)` to return the length.

Comment: Of course! I just checked [the docs of numpy.array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) and they say that the first argument is "array_like: An array, any object exposing the array interface, an object whose `__array__` method returns an array, or any (nested) sequence.
"