# How to pass arguments to function of callable-iterator in python?

Tags: python

Python 2.6.2

```
>>> call_iter = iter(lambda x: x + 1, 100)
>>> call_iter.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

I want to pass argument to `lambda x:x + 1`.

Update: I think the example above is hard to understand.

I wonder whether there is a builtin func like myiter in python:

```
class myiter:
    def __init__(self, callable, initial, sentinel):
        self.value = initial
        self.callable = callable
        self.sentinel = sentinel

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.value == self.sentinel:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            # calculate next value from prev value
            self.value = self.callable(self.value) 
            return self.value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    call_iter = myiter(lambda x:x + 1, 0, 100)
    for i in call_iter:
        print i
```

Comment: This is quite hard to understand.  What sequence of numbers do you want to generate via `call_iter`?

Comment: Does this have to use the callable form of `iter`? Is it the starting number you want to pass?

Comment: Perhaps a custom iterator?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator

Comment: @AdamMihalcin I want to implement a iter, which takes its previous iter.next() return value as its argument of next iter.next().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here, but

```
>>> call_iter = iter(lambda:lambda x: x + 1, 100)
>>> next(call_iter)(1)
2
```

Comment: But since the callable is returning a function, what purpose does the sentinel value of 100 serve?

Comment: @agf, i am still trying to guess that :)

Comment: My thought was he meant something like `call_iter = iter(lambda x=itertools.count().next: x() + 1, 100)` but who knows.

Comment: @agf, I thought something like that is really just an xrange

Comment: I thought maybe for educational purposes he wanted to try the callable form of `iter`.

Comment: @agf, I wait with bated breath for the OP to clarify the question :)

Comment: For `iter(callable, sentinel)`, is `callable` a 0-arg function?

Comment: @xiaochen, yes `iter` calls the function over and over until it returns `sentinel`. There is no way to pass arguments to callable

Answer (score 1):

The form of iter you're trying to use only takes a 0-argument function. The below is for illustration only; don't actually do this.

```
>>> x = 0
>>> def counter():
...     global x
...     x += 1
...     return x
... 
>>> list(iter(counter, 10))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

In general, this form of `iter` isn't very useful. It requires some kind of callable that maintains state between calls. So for example, you could pass the `readline` method of a file object, as suggested in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#iter). But generally, there are better ways to do this. So for example, say you created a class like this:

```
>>> class Incrementer(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.state = 0
...     def __call__(self):
...         rval = self.state
...         self.state += 1
...         return rval
... 
>>> list(iter(Incrementer(), 10))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

It's lovely and all, but if you have to create a class that's supposed to be iterable, you might as well make it a real iterator by giving it a `next` method and an `__iter__` method. Conversely, if you aren't creating a class, just use [`yield`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained)

Answer (score -1):

i think what you want is:

```
call_iter = iter(map(lambda x: x + 1, range(100)))
>>> call_iter.next()
1
>>> call_iter.next()
2
>>> call_iter.next()
3
>>>
```

to pass an argument to the lambda function you need to map the lambda to an iterable like range(100) or [2,4,5]

Comment: I think you should use `imap` otherwise there is little sense using an iterator