# How is a rangeiterator implemented in Python?

Tags: python, iterator

```
>>> reversed(xrange(100))
<rangeiterator object at 0xb72aab78>
>>> it = reversed(xrange(100)).__iter__()
>>> it
<rangeiterator object at 0xb72aa4d0>
>>> next(it)
99
```

How can I implement something like this in Python? To be more spesific, how can I make an iterator, that could be reversed without it being made a list in the memory before it could get reversed?

Comment: You ask how to create an iterator which is reversible using reversed() without becoming too expensive, did I get you right?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you implement the [`__reversed__` magic method](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/datamodel.html#object.__reversed__) on the collection.

The logic for `xrange` is something like:

```
def __reversed__(self):
    return iter(xrange(stop - 1, start - 1, step * -1))
```

There is no trick -- you need to know how to produce a reverse iterator. Python doesn't do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

If your iterator implements the method `__reversed__()`, this will be used by the builtin `reversed()`.  `xrange()` returns iterators which do that.

Answer (score 0):

`reversed` will work with two types of object:

- a sequence (such as a `list`)
- an iterator with the `__reversed__` magic method

If you have a custom sequence, and you can take the `len()` of that sequence, you are good to go -- otherwise, you need to add the `__len__` magic method; if you cannot (e.g. because the length is not known), then you cannot reverse it lazily.

If you have a custom iterator, then make sure it has the `__reversed__` magic method:  `__reversed__` must return a new iterator that goes backwards; again, if you cannot provide one (e.g. because the length is not known), then you cannot lazily reverse it.

*Note*: for more info about creating custom iterables see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7542261/208880).