# Why can't I iterate over an object which delegates via  __getattr__ to an iterable?

Tags: python, python-2.7

An example from the book [Core Python Programming](http://cpp.wesc.webfactional.com/cpp1e/) on the topic `Delegation` doesn't seem to be working.. Or may be I didn't understand the topic clearly..

Below is the code, in which the class `CapOpen` wraps a `file` object and defines a modified behaviour of `file` when opened in `write` mode. It should write all strings in UPPERCASE only.

However when I try to open the file for reading, and iterate over it to print each line, I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/_Python Practice/Core Python Programming/chapter_13_Classes/
        WrappingFileObject.py", line 29, in <module>
    for each_line in f:
TypeError: 'CapOpen' object is not iterable
```

This is strange, because although I haven't explicitly defined iterator methods, I'd expect the calls to be delegated via `__getattr__` to the underlying `file` object. Here's the code. Have I missed anything?

```
class CapOpen(object):
    def __init__(self, filename, mode='r', buf=-1):
        self.file = open(filename, mode, buf)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.file)

    def __repr__(self):
        return `self.file`

    def write(self, line):
        self.file.write(line.upper())

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.file, attr)


f = CapOpen('wrappingfile.txt', 'w')
f.write('delegation example\n')
f.write('faye is good\n')
f.write('at delegating\n')
f.close()

f = CapOpen('wrappingfile.txt', 'r')

for each_line in f:   # I am getting Exception Here..
    print each_line,
```

I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: you need a `__next__` function

Comment: Wouldn't that functionality be delegated to the `file` object through `__getattr__` function??

Comment: Its obviously not ... since your getting a non iterable error ... just return `self.file.__next__()`

Comment: That's what I'm asking.. Why am getting error?? I thought that would be delegated automatically.. BTW, your `self.file.__next__()` didn't work either..

Comment: hmm ... not sure then ... I figured that would work ... sorry

Comment: @JoranBeasley.. It's Ok.. Let's see if I can get any other response..

Comment: Whose downvote was this after 15 days?? And can I know why??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a non-intuitive consequence of a Python [implementation decision for new-style classes](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-special-lookup):

> In addition to bypassing any instance attributes in the interest of
>   correctness, implicit special method lookup generally also bypasses
>   the `__getattribute__()` method even of the object’s metaclass...
>
> Bypassing the `__getattribute__()` machinery in this fashion provides
>   significant scope for speed optimisations within the interpreter, at
>   the cost of some flexibility in the handling of special methods (the
>   special method must be set on the class object itself in order to be
>   consistently invoked by the interpreter).

This is also explicitly pointed out in the documentation for [`__getattr__`/`__getattribute__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__getattr__#object.__getattr__):

> **Note** 
>   This method may still be bypassed when looking up special methods as
>   the result of implicit invocation via language syntax or built-in
>   functions. See *Special method lookup for new-style classes.*

In other words, you can't rely on `__getattr__` to always intercept your method lookups when your attributes are undefined. This is not intuitive, because it is reasonable to expect these implicit lookups to follow the same path as all other clients that access your object. If you call `f.__iter__` directly from other code, it will resolve as expected. However, that isn't the case when called directly from the language.

The book you quote is pretty old, so the original example probably used [old-style classes](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes). If you remove the inheritance from `object`, your code will work as intended. That being said, you should avoid writing old style classes, since they will become obsolete in Python 3. If you want to, you can still maintain the delegation style here by implementing `__iter__` and immediately delegating to the underlying `self.file.__iter__`.

Alternatively, inherit from the `file` object directly and `__iter__` will be available by normal lookup, so that will also work.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with the the methods being in the instance `dict` but not in the `class`.

Comment: @ire_and_curses.. I'm using the latest edition of that book.. And it uses new-style classes for its problem.. Anyways,  that was a nice explanation.. I think I got an idea of why this happens.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For an object to be [iterable](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__iter__#iterator-types), its class has to have `__iter__` or `__getitem__` defined.

[`__getattr__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__getattr__#customizing-attribute-access) is only called when something is being *retrieved* from the instance, but because there are several ways that iteration is supported, Python is looking first to see if the appropriate methods even *exist*.

Try this:

```
class Fake(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print "Nope, no %s here!" % name
        raise AttributeError

f = Fake()
for not_here in f:
    print not_here
```

As you can see, the same error is raised: `TypeError: 'Fake' object is not iterable`.

If you then do this:

```
print '__getattr__' in Fake.__dict__
print '__iter__' in Fake.__dict__
print '__getitem__' in Fake.__dict__
```

You can see what Python is seeing:  that neither `__iter__` nor `__getitem__` exist, so Python does not know how to iterate over it.  While Python *could* just try and then catch the exception, I suspect the reason why it does not is that catching exceptions is quite a bit slower.

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7542261/208880) for the many ways to make an iterator.

Comment: @ire_and_curses: More example added.

Comment: Ok, after much careful reading of the documentation, I now think I understand. I've revised my answer, and removed my downvote on yours, although I don't think the reason for bypassing `getattr` is clear in what you've written (there's no reason Python couldn't resolve `__getattr__` if it really wanted to).

Comment: @ire_and_curses: Thank you for researching, I appreciate it.  I updated my answer again with a possible reason as to why Python doesn't.

Comment: "its class has to have `__iter__` defined" - or `__getitem__` which is used as a fall-back. In this case, iteration happens with increasing indexes, until `IndexError` is thrown.