# What is the interface for python iterators?

Tags: python, interface, iterator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Build a Basic Python Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator)

What are the required methods for defining an iterator? For instance, on the following `Infinity` iterator, are its methods sufficient? Are there other standard or de facto standard methods that define an iterator?

```
class Infinity(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.current = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        self.current += 1
        return self.current
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you have is sufficient for Python 2.x, but in Python 3.x you need to define the function `__next__` instead of `next`, see [PEP 3114](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3114/).

If you need code that is compatible with both 2.x and 3.x, include both.

Comment: @Arion: To define both, just add the statement `__next__ = next` at the end of the body of your class.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [glossary](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-iterator), an iterator is any object with a `next()` method, and a `__iter__()` method.

Answer (score 1):

[Section 4.5 - Iterator Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter)

You need to define for your container:

```
container.__iter__() #-> returns iterator
```

and for your iterator your must define:

```
iterator.__iter__() #-> returns self
iterator.__next__() #-> returns next item
iterator.next() #(for Python2 compatibility) -> returns self.__next__()
```