# Reading a Binary Tree using __iter__

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a standard Binary Tree that reads like
    1
   / \
2  3
/ \ / \
4  5 6  7

I need to read the binary tree by importing my tree class, creating this tree, and then using a for loop to read it like: [4, 2, 5, 1, 6, 3, 7]

I have already made the tree and my program will generate a like tree with any amount of numbers. My problem is in the method.

def **iter**(self):

So far I have:

```
def __iter__(self):
    if self.left:
        self.left.__iter__()
    yield self
    if self.right:
        self.right.__iter__()
```

But when I run a for loop on the tree object like:

for item in tree:
    print("{}: {}").format(item.name, item.height())

It only prints the first node in my try with a correct height.

My question is basically, how to print this binary tree using recursion?

Comment: I was just doing some research about the same thing, and I found this new binarytree module. It already comes with different methods to list the elements or even print the tree strucutre.
[This is the link where I found the module.](https://pypi.org/project/binarytree/) I hope it helps somehow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Python >= [3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380), one can use the `yield from x` syntax for recursive iterators:

```
def __iter__(self):
    if self.left:
        yield from self.left
    yield self
    if self.right:
        yield from self.right
```

Edit: Python 3.3 support confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

Not tried, but probably rather something like:

```
def __iter__(self):
    if self.left:
        for k in self.left:
            yield k
    yield self
    if self.right:
        for k in self.right:
            yield k
```

But check it first.

Comment: Presumably, `for k in self.left` would never enter the body if `self.left` were falsy, making the `if` check redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Next element from the collection should be **returned** by `__next__()`: [What is the interface for python iterators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094421/what-is-the-interface-for-python-iterators)

`__iter__()` should return an iterator, an object that defines `__next__()` method. `yield` is used in generator which is quite different concept than iterators, but you can use generator function (because it is an iterator), i.e.:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, val, a=None, b=None):
        self.left = a
        self.right = b
        self.val = val

    def __iter__(self):
        def generator():
            if self.left:
                for leaf in self.left:
                    yield leaf
            yield self
            if self.right:
                for leaf in self.right:
                    yield leaf
        return generator()

for i in A(3, A(5, A(2), A(1)), A(4)):
    print(i.val)
```