# Iterating through nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, trie

I want to write an iterator for my 'toy' Trie implementation.

Adding already works like this:

```
class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = dict()
        pass
    def add(self, string, value):
        global nops
        current_dict = self.root
        for letter in string:
           nops += 1
           current_dict = current_dict.setdefault(letter, {})
        current_dict = current_dict.setdefault('value', value)              
        pass
```

The output of the adding looks like that:

```
trie = Trie()
trie.add("hello",1)
trie.add("world",2)
trie.add("worlds",12)
print trie.root
{'h': {'e': {'l': {'l': {'o': {'value': 1}}}}}, 'w': {'o': {'r': {'l': {'d': {'s': {'value': 12}, 'value': 2}}}}}}
```

I know, that I need [a `__iter__` and `next` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator).

```
def __iter__(self):
    self.root.__iter__()
    pass

 def next(self):
    print self.root.next()
```

But `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'next'`. How should I do it?

[Update] In the perfect world I would like the output to be one dict with all the words/entries with their corresponding values.

Comment: What do you want the result of iterating over your class to be?

Comment: I think you forgot the initial `"""` at the beginning of your docstring.

Comment: Thanks, I cleaned up and specified my request.

Comment: A couple more things. (1) You never declare `s` in your initial code, so it does not run.  You need to name the second argument `s` or have `for letter in string` instead.  (2) In your sample results, `w o r l d s` should have value 12 according to your samples, not 2.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected these errors as well. The example is a different / minimal version of my code, so that's where the errors come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `__iter__` special method should return an *iterator*; that is, an object of a class that you can call `next` on.  A toy iterator class would be something like:

```
class MyIterator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 10
    def next(self):
        self.i -= 1
        if self.i == 0:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            return self.i
```

Unless you have a natural object to call `iter` on, it's usually easier to make `__iter__` a *generator*:

```
def __iter__(self):
    for i in range(10)
        yield i
```

Here's a stack-based generator iterator for your `Trie`:

```
    def __iter__(self):
        stack = [('', self.root)]
        while stack:
            prefix, d = stack.pop()
            for k, v in d.items():
                if k == 'value':
                    yield prefix, v
                else:
                    stack.append((prefix + k, v))
```

You could also try writing it recursively, although you'd need to use `itertools.chain` or `yield from` (only since Python 3.3).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand correctly what you're looking for in your iterator, I'd do something along these lines (note added field in `__init__`:

```py
class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = dict()
        self.stack = ''

    def add(self, string, value):
        """map it to the given value."""
        global nops
        current_dict = self.root
        for letter in string:
           nops += 1
           current_dict = current_dict.setdefault(letter, {})
        current_dict = current_dict.setdefault('value', value)              
        pass

    def __iter__(self, input_dict=None):
        if not input_dict:
            input_dict = self.root

        if 'value' in input_dict:
            yield (self.stack, input_dict['value'])

        keys = [x for x in input_dict.keys() if x != 'value']
        for key in keys:
            self.stack += key
            for item in self.__iter__(input_dict[key]):
                yield item
            self.stack = self.stack[:-1]
```

That would give you:

```py
trie = Trie()
trie.add("hello", 1)
trie.add("world", 2)
trie.add("worlds", 12)
print trie.root
print [x for x in trie]

# {'h': {'e': {'l': {'l': {'o': {'value': 1}}}}}, 'w': {'o': {'r': {'l': {'d': {'s': {'value': 12}, 'value': 2}}}}}}
# [('hello', 1), ('world', 2), ('worlds', 12)]
```

So, it is possible to do this recursively without `itertools.chain` or `yield from`.