# Why won't my class that returns a list iterate?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, iterator

Here is my code, I use it to open an excel sheet and then return each row as a list of strings (where each cell is a string). The class returns one list that is filled with as many lists as there are rows in the file. So 50 rows will return 50 lists.

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

class ExcelReadLines(object):

    def __init__(self,path_to_file):
        '''Accepts the Excel File'''
        self.path_to_file = path_to_file
        self.__work__()


    def __work__(self):
        self.full_file_as_read_lines = []
        self.book = open_workbook(self.path_to_file)
        self.sheet = self.book.sheet_by_index(0)

        for row_index in range(self.sheet.nrows):
            single_read_lines = []
            for col_index in range(self.sheet.ncols):
                cell_value_as_string = str(self.sheet.cell(row_index,col_index).value)
                cell_value_stripped = cell_value_as_string.strip('u')
                single_read_lines.append(cell_value_stripped)
            self.full_file_as_read_lines.append(single_read_lines)

        return self.full_file_as_read_lines
```

But when I run:

```
for x in ExcelReader('excel_sheet'): print x
```

I get the error message:

```
class is not iterable
```

Answer (score 7):

In order for a class to be iterable, it needs to have an `__iter__` method.

Consider:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self,lst):
        self.lst = lst
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.lst)
```

example:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self,lst):
...         self.lst = lst
...     def __iter__(self):
...         return iter(self.lst)
... 
>>> Foo([1,2,3])
<__main__.Foo object at 0xe9890>
>>> for x in Foo([1,2,3]): print x
... 
1
2
3
```

---

Your example seems like it would be a good bit better as a generator -- I don't really understand what the need is for a class here:

```
def excel_reader(path_to_file):
    book = open_workbook(path_to_file)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

    for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
        single_read_lines = []
        for col_index in range(sheet.ncols):
            cell_value_as_string = str(self.sheet.cell(row_index,col_index).value)
            cell_value_stripped = cell_value_as_string.strip('u')
            single_read_lines.append(cell_value_stripped)
        yield single_read_lines
```

Comment: I've look around and that seems to be the consensus. But I can't understand how to use it to return a list of lists.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into implementing Python's [special iterator methods](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types).

Also, note that you shouldn't name a method `__work__` since it uses magic method syntax but isn't actually a real magic method.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems here.

1. Your code doesn't return anything.  You call `__work__` but don't return the value.
2. Even if it did, that wouldn't help, because returning something from `__init__` doesn't make the object be that thing.
3. You don't want your object to *be* a list anyway, you just want to iterate over it.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator) for a simple example of how to write an iterator in Python.

In addition, you shouldn't use double-underscore-sandwich names like `__work__` in your code.  That sort of name is by convention reserved for Python-internal use.

Comment: I don't understand your first point. I believe that it does return a value. init call the work method, and the work method returns a list.

Also, I would like a list of lists, this way I can sort each list according to an algorithm and put each list into either one bucket or another.

Comment: @user1367204 -- To return a value from a function, you need the `return` statement.  And, python doesn't respect values `return`ed from `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, what you're really after is

```
def first_sheet(fname):
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(fname)
    ws = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
    for i in xrange(ws.nrows):
        yield ws.row_values(i) # maybe strip 'u''s - but that looks a bit sus... (probably something to do with your `str`)

list_of_rows = list(first_sheet('somefile.xls'))
```

Then do any transposition using `zip` if needs be...