# stay on same value in python iterator

Tags: python, iterator

I'm creating an `interator` like so:

```
some_list = [1,2,5,12,30,75,180,440]
iter(some_list)
```

I have a need to access the current value of an iterator again. Is there a `current()` method that allows me to stay on the same position?

Comment: Could you expand your question? (Maybe with how this code would be used.) I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Are you looking for [`itertools.tee`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee)?

Comment: Also, if you want to access the values repeatedly, why create an iterator instead of just returning the list?

Comment: Why not use a local variable to capture the last output of the iterable? Then if you don't want to move to the next element you can use the local variable's contents.

Comment: If you say why you need to do this, maybe a better method can be suggested

Comment: There is a tool `numpy.nditer` which does exactly what you want and more. See my answer below for demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly *can* make a class which will allow you to do this:

```
from collections import deque

class RepeatableIter(object):
    def __init__(self,iterable):
        self.iter = iter(iterable)
        self.deque = deque([])
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    #define `next` and `__next__` for forward/backward compatability
    def next(self):
        if self.deque:
            return self.deque.popleft()
        else:
            return next(self.iter)
    __next__ = next

    def requeue(self,what):
        self.deque.append(what)


x = RepeatableIter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
count = 0
for i in x:
    print i
    if i == 4 and count == 0:
        count += 1
        x.requeue(i)
```

The question is really why would you want to?

Comment: Don't miss `numpy.nditer` which does exactly what the OP requires.

Comment: Having to re-add the item, plus having to take special care to not get into an infinite loop, is not user-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.nditer` to build your iterator, then you have many amazing options including the current `value`.

```
import numpy

rng = range(100)
itr = numpy.nditer([rng])
print itr.next()          #0
print itr.next()          #1
print itr.next()          #2

print itr.value           #2 : current iterator value
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the third example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7542261/208880):

```
class CurrentIterator():

    _sentinal = object()
    _current = _sentinal

    @property
    def current(self):
        if self._current is self._sentinal:
            raise ValueError('No current value')
        return self._current

    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.it = iter(iterable)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            self._current = current = next(self.it)
        except StopIteration:
            self._current = self._sentinal
            raise
        return current
    next = __next__  # for python2.7 compatibility
```

Some interesting points:

- use of `_sentinal` so an error can be raised if no current value exists
- use of `property` so `current` looks like a simple attribute
- use of `__next__` and `next = __next__` for Python 2&3 compatibility

Comment: I would suggest not using a property here... raising a `ValueError` in a property when it hasn't been set seems funky, (`AttributeError` seems more appropriate), but since it is getting set magically ... Also there doesn't seem to be a lot of reason to allow the user to _set_ the current value.  I'd just use `.current()` and maintain the state of `_current` internally.  But that's just my 2c.  In any event, I think this implementation is probably better than mine -- though the original question I posed to the user is still valid.  Why would you want this in the first place :-).

Comment: @mgilson: Very good point about the setter; implemented and thanks!.