# How to make class data sortable

Tags: python, sorting

This is surely a duplicate, but say I have a class as follows:

```
class MyObj(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._data = [2, 1, 3]
        self._more_data = [False, True, False]
```

How can I make it sortable, not against other MyObj objects (which I could do with `__lt__`), but internally? So if I call `sorted(my_obj_instance)` I get a version with data like:

```
self._data = [1,2,3]
self._more_data [True, False, False]
```

That is, _data is sorted numerically, and _more_data has been sorted correspondingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sorted()` **never** modifies the original data. To make it work with a custom object you'd have to implement `__iter__` though (returning e.g. `iter(self._data)`) - but that would just give you a sorted version of that object and neither modify your original object nor sort both lists.

What you want is a `sort()` method which you'd call as `yourobj.sort()`. This method would then call `.sort()` on the lists with an appropriate `key` argument for the way you want them sorted.

Comment: If "sorted" order is more important - then I'm wondering if the OP should re-consider the data structure and keep those items in something else..., but yeah +1

Comment: Yeah, the example is just to make the need for a custom sort method clear, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can't make `sorted` return an instance of your class.  `sorted` always returns a list.  If you make it [an iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator) you can get `sorted` to return a sorted version of your class's data (as a list).  But it's probably simpler to just give your class a method called `sort` that sorts its data.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a `sort` method like this

```
def sort(self)
    self._data, self._more_data = zip(*sorted(zip(self._data, self._more_data)))
```

This zips the two attributes into 2-tuples. Does the sort over the list of 2-tuples and unzips them again.