# Skipping yield in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, generator, yield

I'm writing a `generator` that takes an `iterable` and an integer `n`. For example if I call my generator:

```
generator('abcdefg',2)
```

then it should yield `a`, `d`, `g` skipping 2 letters.

When I call `iter(iterable)` then use `yield next` the `yield` automatically skips 1 letter. How would I tell python to skip yielding so I can skip `n` letters?

Answer (score 3):

Your generator is effectively `islice` with a step parameter, so you could wrap the original `iterable` as such:

```
from itertools import islice

def generator(iterable, skip):
    return islice(iterable, None, None, skip+1)

for item in generator('abcdefg', 2):
    print(item)
# a
# d
# g
```

If you wanted to write it by hand, then perhaps a simple way to understand is first `yield`'ing from the iterable, then consuming from the iterable the gap size...

```
def generator(iterable, skip):
    it = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        yield next(it)
        for _ in range(skip):
            next(it)
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you want

```
def generator(string, skip):
    for i,c in enumerate(string):
        if i % (skip+1)==0:
            yield c
```

This doesn't actually "skip" yield statements, that is every yield is executed.  However, yield is only called at fixed intervals of the iteration over string characters.

Answer (score 0):

The basic framework using a [custom iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7542261/208880):

```
class skipper():
    def __init__(self, iterable, skip_count):
        self.it = iter(iterable)
        self.skip = skip_count
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        value = next(self.it)
        for _ in range(self.skip):
            next(self.it, None)
        return value
```

You could easily add any other behaviour you needed to this class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by simply using **next()** function

```
def make_generator():
    for x in range(1, 10):
        yield x


my_generator = make_generator()


def generator(temp_generator, num):  # generator('abcdefg',2)
    for x in range(num):
        next(temp_generator)
    for y in temp_generator:
        print(y)  # Skipped Value of generator
generator(my_generator, 2)
```

Output: 3
4
5
6
7
8
9