# How can I implement a function in Python that conditionally behaves as a context manager?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
import unittest
from contextlib import contextmanager


def outer(with_context=False):
    def inner():
        # Some code here

        if with_context:
            with unittest.TestCase().assertRaises(KeyError):
                yield
        else:
            print("No context")

        # Some more code here

    if with_context:
        return contextmanager(inner)
    else:
        return inner


no_context_func = outer()
no_context_func()  # "No context" does not get printed

my_dict = {"valid_key": 123}

context_func = outer(with_context=True)
with context_func():
    my_dict["valid_key"]  # Works fine
```

Why is "No context" not printed to the console? In fact, it seems that the function call to `no_context_func` is skipped completely, as I can not set a break point at the `print("No context")` line. Removing the content of the `if with_context:` branch prints "No context" but why does the yield influence the program execution although it is not in a branch that gets executed?

Edit:
I have added comments to the code example showing that there is more code before and after the if/else in the inner function. I eventually want to use `outer` as a decorator that I can parameterize and that I can use to decorate regular functions and context managers, like `assertRaises`. My question is whether there is a way of using the same decorator for both cases or if I will have to use separate decorators, one for regular functions and one for context managers. That unfortunately means that I have to duplicate the content of the inner function.

Comment: `no_context_func()` is *defined* in the `outer()` but only executed if a truthy argument is passed to `outer()` when it's executed (regardless of the assigning the function to a variable with a different name.

Comment: @martineau That doesn't sound right. What do you mean with "only executed if"? I mean, it does get executed (and returns an iterator).

Comment: @KellyBundy: I meant just defining a function doesn't execute the code in it — it must be *called* from somewhere afterwards for that to happen.

Comment: @martineau Their `no_context_func()` does call it. Unless you meant the resulting iterator isn't called? But that's not even callable...

Comment: @KellyBundy: The `no_context_func()` aka the `outer()` function doesn't necessarily call it.

Comment: @martineau `no_context_func` isn't `outer` but the result of calling `outer`, i.e., it's `inner`. And the `()` at the end of `no_context_func()` means calling it. So they **do** call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `inner` is a generator function and `no_context_func()` thus returns a generator iterator. Whose code is only executed when you iterate it. So you get your desired effect (printing "No context") if you for example replace `return inner` with `return lambda: next(inner(), None)`.

Comment: That's the correct answer, thank you very much! The only drawback is that the function signature of `inner` gets lost.

Comment: What do you mean with signature?

Comment: My `inner` function is actually a wrapt decorator that I use to wrap other functions. Autocompletion for the `with_context` case works fine, conserving the signature of the wrapped function. However, it's not preserved for the cases where the lambda is returned. Nonetheless, the docstring is still preserved which lists the arguments and their types so I'm happy with that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah, ok. Maybe the functools wrap stuff could help, I'm not familiar with that.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `yield` to a function turns it into generator, which work quite differently than standard functions. Consider the following basic generator example:

```
def mygenerator():
    print('First item')
    yield 10

    print('Second item')
    yield 20

    print('Last item')
    yield 30

a = mygenerator()
print("calling next")
print(next(a))
```

As you can see, `print('First item')` only happened after `next` was called for the first time, even though with standard function it would happen at `a = mygenerator()` call already.

My question is, what is the point of your yield statement here?

Comment: *"As you can see"* - I can't. Did you intend to show the output but then forgot?

Comment: The point of the `yield` is to satisfy `contextmanager`.

Comment: Looks like a I can not achieve my goal. According to the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47683745/python-functions-as-optional-generators): "The reason is that occurrence of yield anywhere in the function makes it a generator function. There's no way to have a function that decides at call time whether it's a generator function or not. Instead, you have to have a non-generator function that decides at runtime whether to return a generator or something else."

Comment: The problem is that I have code before and after the if/else block and now I have to duplicate stuff to a degree.

Comment: @Mr-Pepe In the no-context case you could just consume the generator iterator, that'd execute its code.

Comment: @KellyBundy I tried and did not succeed. I have updated my question to explain a bit more what I am trying to achieve. Let me know if you have any ideas.