# Filtering whilst using numpy.genfromtxt

Tags: python, numpy

I have a file from which I only need to read certain values into an array. The file is divided by rows which specify a `TIMESTEP` value. I need the section of data following the highest `TIMESTEP` in the file.

The files will contain over 200,000 rows although I won't know which row the section I need begins for any given file and I won't know what the largest `TIMESTEP` value will be.

Am assuming that if I can find the row number of the largest `TIMESTEP` then I can import starting at that line. All these `TIMESTEP` lines begin with a space character. Any ideas on how I might proceed would be helpful.

**Sample file**

```
 headerline 1 to skip
 headerline 2 to skip
 headerline 3 to skip
 TIMESTEP =    0.00000000    
0,    1.0,   1.0,    1.0,   1.0,      1.0,   1.0
1,    1.0,   1.0,    1.0,   1.0,      1.0,   1.0
2,    1.0,   1.0,    1.0,   1.0,      1.0,   1.0
2,    1.0,   1.0,    1.0,   1.0,      1.0,   1.0
 TIMESTEP =   0.119999997    
0,    1.0,   1.0,    1.0,   1.0,      1.0,   1.0
1,    1.0,   1.0,    1.0,   1.0,      1.0,   1.0
2,    1.0,   1.0,    1.0,   1.0,      1.0,   1.0
3,    1.0,   1.0,    1.0,   1.0,      1.0,   1.0
 TIMESTEP =    3.00000000    
0,    1.0,   1.0,    1.0,   1.0,      1.0,   1.0
1,    1.0,   1.0,    1.0,   1.0,      1.0,   1.0
1,    1.0,   1.0,    1.0,   1.0,      1.0,   1.0
2,    1.0,   1.0,    1.0,   1.0,      1.0,   1.0
```

**Basic code**

```
import numpy as np

with open('myfile.txt') as f_in:
  data = np.genfromtxt(f_in, skip_header=3, comments=" ")
```

Comment: I'd use regular Python file reading to find the correct TIMESTEP block.

Comment: You might not even need `genfromtxt` to extract the data from the desired lines.  Or load them into a `StringIO` buffer, and run `genfromtxt` on that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @hpaulj. I'll give that a shot. If you wanted to provide a basic example that would be awesome. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use a custom [iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator).

Here is a working example:

from numpy import genfromtxt

```
class Iter(object):
    ' a custom iterator which returns a timestep and corresponding data '

    def __init__(self, fd):
        self.__fd = fd
        self.__timestep = None
        self.__next_timestep = None
        self.__finish = False
        for _ in self.to_next_timestep(): pass # skip header

    def to_next_timestep(self):
        ' iterate until next timestep '
        for line in self.__fd:
            if 'TIMESTEP' in line:
                self.__timestep = self.__next_timestep
                self.__next_timestep = float(line.split('=')[1])
                return
            yield line
        self.__timestep = self.__next_timestep
        self.__finish = True

    def __iter__(self): return self

    def next(self):
        if self.__finish:
            raise StopIteration
        data = genfromtxt(self.to_next_timestep(), delimiter=',')
        return self.__timestep, data

with open('myfile.txt') as fd:
    iter = Iter(fd)
    for timestep, data in iter:
        print timestep, data # data can be selected upon highest timestep
```

Comment: I am getting an error where it won't read in the last section: 

UserWarning: genfromtxt: Empty input file: "<generator object to_next_timestep at 0x107bdd050>"
  warnings.warn('genfromtxt: Empty input file: "%s"' % fname)

Comment: it's not an error, it's a warning :) the last section should read fine. You can easily catch the warning, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html

Comment: Sorry, "warning" not "error". If I print the `timestep` values as I iterate though, it returns the second last `timestep` value twice, although `data` is correct.

0.0
0.119999997
0.119999997

Comment: Oh yes right. Fixed :) And the warning also goes away.

Answer (score 2):

You can precisely use `filter()` whilst using `genfromtxt()`, because `genfromtxt` accepts generators.

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'rb') as f_in:
    lines = filter(lambda x: not x.startswith(b' '), f_in)
    data = genfromtxt(lines, delimiter=',')
```

Then in your case you don't need to `skip_header`.

Comment: Thanks! That gets the bulk of the data imported but what I really need is the section of data which comes _after_ the `TIMESTEP` line with the highest value. In this case, the section after `TIMESTEP = 3.00000000` Ideally without needing to iterate the whole file multiple times.

Comment: ok sorry I did not get your question. I'll post another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses a regular Python file read, applying `genfromtxt` to a list of lines.  For illustration purposes I am parsing each block of data, but it could be easily modified to skip blocks that don't meet your timestep criteria.

I first wrote this with `StringIO`, as used in many of the `genfromtxt` doc examples, but all it needs is an iterable.  So a list of lines works just fine.

```
import numpy as np
filename = 'stack26008436.txt'

def parse(tstep, block):
    print tstep
    print np.genfromtxt(block, delimiter=',')

with open(filename) as f:
    block = []
    for line in f:
        if 'TIMESTEP' in line:
            if block:
                parse(tstep, block)
            block = []
            tstep = float(line.strip().split('=')[1])
        else:
            if 'header' not in line:
                block.append(line)
    parse(tstep, block)
```

producing from your sample:

```
0901:~/mypy$ python2.7 stack26008436.py
0.0
[[ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 ...
 [ 3.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]
3.0
[[ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 2.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]
```