# numpy: How to load a bounded (R1 C1 to R2 C2) matrix from file

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for the numpy equivalent of Matlab's

`M = dlmread(filename,delimiter,[R1 C1 R2 C2])`

In numpy's `loadtxt`, I found that you can skip first `n` rows and load selected columns but there is now way to say how to limit the rows to a fixed upper bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`genfromtxt` has an additional `skip_footer` argument but you need to know total number of lines in your file.

Or you could read the whole file and then slice over the portion you want:

```
M = loadtxt (filename, delimiter=delimiter) [R1:R2+1,C1:C2+1]
```

Or

```
M = loadtxt (filename, delimiter=delimiter, usecols=range(C1,C2+1)) [R1:R2+1,:]
```

**Update:**
Following hpaulj suggestion you could also define a custom iterator and use that with `genfromtxt` (in which case you don't need to know the total number of lines in the file and you don't need to construct a bigger matrix first). For example:

```
class file_iterator ():
    def __init__ (self, filename, begin, end):
        self.file = open (filename)
        self.line_number = 0
        self.begin = begin
        self.end = end

    def __iter__ (self): return self

    def next (self):
        for line in self.file:
            self.line_number += 1
            if self.begin <= self.line_number <= self.end:
                return line
        raise StopIteration
```

And then use:

```
M = genfromtxt (file_iterator(filename, R1, R2), delimiter=delimiter, cols=range(C1,C2+1))
```

Comment: `genfromtxt` takes any iterable that gives it lines.  That could be a generator that returns the specified number of lines.

Comment: There are several examples in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26008436/filtering-whilst-using-numpy-genfromtxt