# Dictionary iteration with iter func

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, dictionary, iterator

Im trying to iter on my dictionary useing this :

```
it = iter(db)
for i in it:
    print(i)
```

but when i run this what happens is an endless loop of printing the dictionary as a whole rather then on the keys of the dictionary

i use this as input :

```
ppl = Course(123, 'Principles of Programming Languages') 
os = Course(133, 'Operating Systems') 
db = DB()
db.setCourse(ppl, 'SE', 2, 1)
db.setCourse(os, 'SE', 3, 1)
```

and my output is:

```
{123: ('Principles of Programming Languages', 'SE', 2, 1), 133: ('Operating Systems', 'SE', 3, 1)}
{123: ('Principles of Programming Languages', 'SE', 2, 1), 133: ('Operating Systems', 'SE', 3, 1)}
{123: ('Principles of Programming Languages', 'SE', 2, 1), 133: ('Operating Systems', 'SE', 3, 1)}
```

in a loop that never ends.
im pretty sure that my **next** is messed up.

EDIT
the DB code is long this is the iter part of it :

```
class DB()
    DataBase = {} 
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.DataBase)
    def getCourse(self,cnum):
        for i in self.DataBase:
            if i == cnum:
                return self.DataBase[i]
    def getCoursesByDept(self,dept):
        for key, value in self.DataBase.items(): 
            if dept in value: 
                return self.DataBase[key]
    def getCoursesByDeptYear(self,dept,year):
        for key, value in self.DataBase.items():
            if dept in value and year in value:
                return self.DataBase[key]
    def getCoursesByDeptYearSem(self,dept,year,semester):
        for key, value in self.DataBase.items():
            if dept in value and year in value and semester in value:
                return self.DataBase[key]
    def setCourse(self,Course,dept,year,semester):
        self.DataBase[Course.cnum] = (Course.name,dept,year,semester)
    def removeCourse(self,cnum):
        for i in self.DataBase.keys():
            if i == cnum:
                del self.DataBase[i]
```

the correct output is :

```
Course 123: Principles of Programming Languages 
Course 133: Operating Systems
```

Comment: You forgot to share the code of `DB` class.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't reproduce the problem. Also, you don't need a separate `iter`

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: this is a HW assignment and she demands that we ether use the iter func or create one of my own, i rather use the exciting one xD

Comment: You want to iterate through the keys in `DataBase`?

Comment: yes i do, and then to get the output, i belive that i will allso need some kind of an __STR__ func for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the easiest fix is:

```
class DB():
    ...
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.DataBase)
```

and take out the `__next__` method.

To create your own, you need to walk through the keys yourself in your `__iter__`:

```
    def __iter__(self):
        for key in self.Database:
            yield key
```

which creates a generator, and you still don't need a `__next__`; if you *have* to have a `__next__`, then you'll need to gather the keys, and then return them one by one.

Once you have return each and every key, you need to `raise StopIteration` everytime `__next__` is called again -- meaning you can only iterate once -- better to stick with one of the above two options.

The reason you are currently getting an infinite loop is that everytime `__next__` is called you return the entire dictionary -- no checks to see if you're done.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7542261/208880) for a more thorough explanation of creating iterators.

---

If you want your `DB` class to look the same as a `dict`, then add `keys()`, `items()`, and `values()`; if you don't care or won't need those, then either the second option above, or create your own.  The second option might look like:

```
    def __iter__(self):
        for key, value in self.Database.items():
            yield key, value
```

What happens here is that for every `key`, `value` pair in `DB`, both are return when iterating.  So your original loop should look like:

```
it = iter(db)
for k, v in it:
    print('%s: %s' % (k, v))
```

Comment: This returns me only the key, i must have another problems somewhere in the code.

Comment: @Mike.G: When one iterates over a dictionary, the key is what is returned -- there are other methods to return other things: `.values()` to return just the values, and `__items__` to return just the items.

Comment: i see, then how do i change it to return me the desired output?

Comment: @Mike.G: See the linked answer.  :)

Comment: i ment to say that the resault is not what i need =[