# How to make an object both a Python2 and Python3 iterator?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, iterator

[This Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator) is about making an object an iterator in Python.

In Python 2, that means you need to implement an `__iter__()` method, and a `next()` method. But in Python 3, you need to implement a *different* method, instead of `next()` you need to implement `__next__()`.

How does one make an object which is an iterator in both Python 2 and 3?

Comment: I've edited in all the parts you should have included in the first place. Please try to formulate a question that stands on its own, and is not merely a reference to another post.

Comment: and now it is a nice question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just give it both `__next__` and `next` method; one can be an alias of the other:

```
class Iterator(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        # Python 3
        return 'a value'

    next = __next__  # Python 2
```