# Generator is not an iterator?

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I have an generator (a function that yields stuff), but when trying to pass it to `gensim.Word2Vec` I get the following error:

> TypeError: You can't pass a generator as the sentences argument. Try an iterator.

Isn't a generator a kind of iterator? If not, how do I make an iterator from it?

Looking at the library code, it seems to simply iterate over sentences like `for x in enumerate(sentences)`, which works just fine with my generator. What is causing the error then?

Comment: Well ... They went to a lot of trouble to prevent you from using generators:  https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/blob/839513f81e3aa42f490331fa80a28d13b7b7026f/gensim/models/word2vec.py#L434

Comment: That makes no damn sense.

Comment: @user2357112 -- Perhaps the input needs to be iterated over multiple times.  The docs say that a list is an OK input.  (Of course, in that case `iterator` is definitely the _wrong_ term to put in the error message).

Comment: @riv Then you can just change your generator to a list comprehesion.

Comment: [I found the issue the check was supposed to address.](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/issues/319) It doesn't look like the people in the comment chain had a clear understanding of the vocabulary at the time. This error message should definitely be changed (and perhaps they should add `or iter(sentences) is iter(sentences)` to catch other iterator types).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Generator is **exhausted** after one loop over it. Word2vec simply needs to traverse sentences multiple times (and probably get item for a given index, which is not possible for generators which are just a kind of stacks where you can only pop), thus requiring something more solid, like a list.

In particular in their code they call two different functions, both iterate over sentences (thus if you use generator, the second one would run on an empty set)

```
self.build_vocab(sentences, trim_rule=trim_rule)
self.train(sentences)
```

It should work with anything implementing `__iter__`  which is not `GeneratorType`. So wrap your function in an iterable interface and make sure that you can traverse it multiple times, meaning that

```
sentences = your_code
for s in sentences:
  print s
for s in sentences:
  print s
```

prints your collection twice

Comment: All iterators are exhausted after one loop, not only those created by generators. (Continuing to raise `StopIteration` on subsequent calls to `next` after exhaustion is a requirement, in fact.) The error message probably meant to say **iterable** instead of **iterator**. Some iterables can be looped over many times, as correctly explained in your answer.

Comment: I see, but wouldn't an iterator only be iterable once if it returns self in `__iter__`? I'm also thinking that the error message meant to say iterable.

Comment: @riv An iterator **has** to return `self` in `__iter__`. An *iterable* doesn't, however, it can (and does in case of built-in containers) return a new iterator that starts at the beginning.

Comment: I just made a class that returns my generator in the `__iter__` method (and has no other methods) and it worked.

Comment: @riv It may *look* like it's working because you're no longer getting an exception, but is it working correctly? If both `build_vocab` and `train` iterate over the `sentences` iterator, `train` will encounter an empty iterator. It's very likely the code doesn't train at all. The proper fix is explained by Alex Volkov, except it can be spelled more shortly as `list(generator_obj)`.

Comment: Interesting [comment from Guido](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4707#issuecomment-487091762) around this that suggests there was never a guarantee that Iterables could be re-used and the error is with functions accepting Iterable then assuming they could iterate multiple times.

Answer (score 8):

As previous posters are mentioned, generator acts similarly to iterator with two significant differences: generators get exhausted, and you can't index one.

I quickly looked up the documentation, on this page -- https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html

The documentation states that

*gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec(sentences=None, size=100, alpha=0.025, window=5, min_count=5, max_vocab_size=None, sample=0, seed=1, workers=1, min_alpha=0.0001, sg=1, hs=1, negative=0, cbow_mean=0, hashfxn=, iter=1, null_word=0, trim_rule=None, sorted_vocab=1)*
    ...

*Initialize the model from an iterable of sentences. Each sentence is a list of words (unicode strings) that will be used for training.*

I'm venture to guess that the logic inside of the function inherently requires one or more list properties such as item indexing, there might be an explicit assert statement or if statement that raises an error.

A simple hack that can solve your problem is turning your generator into list comprehension. Your program is going to sustain CPU performance penalty and will increase its memory usage, but this should at least make the code work.

```
my_iterator = [x for x in generator_obj]
```

Comment: Note that list created by the comprehension in your answer is an iterable (has an `__iter__` method), but not an iterator (has no `next` method).

Comment: Yes you're right, it's list comprehension, not iterator, I'll change my answer.

Comment: But it means that you can't train word2vec on a very large corpus. Gensim library, however, prides itself on being memory-efficient.

Comment: @osa This was a quick solution for this particular problem. You will likely need to write something more involved for your case i.e. implement your own iterator that could be cycled multiple times, where you can trade off memory use for I/O, by re-reading a file several times, see -- sample iterator http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator; see itertools.cycle -- https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle

Answer (score 4):

Other answers have pointed out that Gensim requires two passes to build the `Word2Vec` model: once to build the vocabulary (`self.build_vocab`), and the second to train the model (`self.train`). You can still pass a generator to the `train` method (e.g., if you're streaming data) by breaking apart the `build_vocab` and `train` methods.

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

model = Word2Vec()
sentences = my_generator()  # first pass
model.build_vocab(sentences)

sentences = my_generator()  # second pass of same data
model.train(sentences2, 
            total_examples=num_sentences,  # total number of documents to process
            epochs=model.epochs)
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems gensim throws a misleading error message.

Gensim wants to iterate over your data multiple times. Most libraries just build a list from the input, so the user doesn't have to care about supplying a multiple iterable sequence. Of course, generating an in-memory list can be very resource-consuming, while iterating over a file for example, can be done without storing the whole file in memory.

In your case, just changing the generator to a list comprehesion should solve the problem.