# How to use the iterator class?

Tags: python, iterator

Im trying to create a iterator class that will give me a path throw a tree graph, which every iteration it will return the next step according to certain conditions.

So i looked up how to do this here : [Build a Basic Python Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/how-to-make-class-iterable)

and this is what i wrote so far :

```
def travel_path_iterator(self, article_name):
    return Path_Iter(article_name)


class Path_Iter:

    def __init__(self,article):
        self.article=article

    def __iter__(self):
        return next(self)

    def __next__(self):
        answer= self.article.get_max_out_nb()
        if answer != self.article.get_name():
            return answer
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

But I have a problem to call this class. 
my output is always :

```
<__main__.Path_Iter object at 0x7fe94049fc50>
```

any guesses what im doing wrong ?

Comment: What output? Your code does not output anything.

Comment: your `__next__`-method looks weird. Does `get_max_out_nb` results in the next answer each time called?

Comment: It would be simpler to write a generator function yielding values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `Path_Iter` is already an iterator, the `__iter__`-method should return `self`:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return self
```

Next, to iterate an iterator, you need some kind of loop. E.g. to print the contents, you could convert the iterator to a list:

```
print list(xyz.travel_path_iterator(article_name))
```

Comment: i write this in the iterator class or in the function ?
there is no need to recursion right ?

Comment: where i need to print list(xyz.travel_path_iterator(article_name))? 
in the PathIter class ?

Comment: outside the class, it's an example, how you can use iterators.

Answer (score 0):

Using a generator function:

```
def travel_path_generator(article):
    while True:
        answer = article.get_max_out_nb()
        if answer == article.get_name()
            break
        else:
            yield answer
```