# What is the use of returning self in the __iter__ method?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def __iter__(self):
    return self
```

Just wanted to know what does the above code do in general, why is it required.

I went through many code tutorial and blocks, was getting mutiple answers without any proper specification, just a brief explanation would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make class iterable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/how-to-make-class-iterable)

Comment: @vaultah ya its from the iterable  code section, I have seen this section in many other methods, so I just wanted to know why we use this part of code in general

Comment: What do you mean? Did you read the answer on the linked page? *"The `__iter__` returns the iterator object and is implicitly called at the start of loops"* is the answer to your question.

Comment: yes I have read it, and just like others it ain't clearing the logic

Comment: Fluent Python, chapter 14 → http://www.amazon.com/Fluent-Python-Luciano-Ramalho/dp/1491946008/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT: for 2.7 instead of 3

Here is my understanding

In below example code, we can say that class Testing is an iterable object because we implemented it with `__iter__`. Method `__iter__` returns an iterator. The iterator uses the next method to determine the next value on the iteration. If I were to remove the `next` method from the class below, the code would fail.

iterable = an object that can be iterated over...implemented with `__iter__`

iterator = object that defines how to iterate...literally, what is the next value. This is implemented with `__next__`

So the piece of code you questioned actually takes the class object (self is the argument) and returns an iterator, which makes the class object iterable. So in the example below we can actually iterate over the class object myObj.

```
class Testing:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def __iter__ (self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        if self.a <= self.b:
            self.a += 1
            return self.a-1
        else:
            raise StopIteration

myObj = Testing(1,5)           
for i in myObj:
    print i
```

Answer (score 12):

It's a bit confusing. In short, defining `__iter__` to `return self` is essentially turning an iterator object into an iterable quickly so that you can use it in a `for` loop.

Recall that an iterator is an object with a `next` method for the purpose of returning the next item in the process of performing an iteration. After the `next` method is called, the state of the iterator changes.

Recall that an iterable is an object with an `__iter__` method, whose purpose is to return a fresh iterator to perform an iteration.

To separate the concepts, let's take the example of the iterator `OneToFourIterator` and the iterable `OneToFourIterable`

```
class OneToFourIterator:
  def __init__(self):
    self.state = 0
  def next(self):
    self.state += 1
    if self.state > 4:
      raise StopIteration
    return self.state
    
class OneToFourIterable:
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  def __iter__(self):
    return OneToFourIterator()
```

To perform a iteration using a `for` loop, you have to give it an iterable like this,

```
for i in OneToFourIterable():
  print i
```

If you use an iterator in a `for` loop, it will give an error. To use an iterator for iteration, you would do something like this

```
iterator = OneToFourIterator()
while True:
  try:
    current = iterator.next()
    print current
  except StopIteration:
    break
```

Finally, I think the answer to why people define `__iter__` to `return self`, is that instead of writing 2 classes like the above, you can quickly turn an iterator into an iterable so that you can use it in a `for` loop:

```
class OneToFourIteratorAndIterable:
  def __init__(self):
    self.state = 0
  def next(self):
    self.state += 1
    if self.state > 4:
      raise StopIteration
    return self.state
    pass
  def __iter__(self):
    return self

for i in OneToFourIteratorAndIterable():
  print i
```

Comment: To be iterable, the object that is returned by ```__iter__``` must have a ```__next__``` method defined. This is why iterator classes return self in the ```__iter__```. It's because the class defines the ```__next__```

Comment: Does this mean returning `self` in `__iter()__` is actually incorrect? Because `self` is not necessarily a new iterator in a clean state. I just tried it out and it seems so.

Answer (score 3):

It also confused me for a little time. :)
OK ,let's see a `for` loop in Python:

```
for i in a:
    print i
```

In this snippet, the `for` loop will implicitly call `a.__iter__()`, which should be an iterator. What's more, in Python, if you want an iterator, the class must implement the *iterator* interface, which means it should have both `__iter__` and `__next__`, and the effect of `__iter__` is to return an iterator.

However, there is another concept in Python that is called iterable, it is a factory which can produce iterators.

OK, now, what we want is ***can iter either iterator or iterable***, so, their `__iter__` method must return an iterator.

For iterable, it should return an iterator (probably another class which implements the *iterator* interface), and for iterator, yeah, itself is an iterator, so just return itself!

The following snippet is copied from *Fluent Python:*

```
import reprlib

RE_WORD = re.compile('\w+')


class Sentence:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
        self.words = RE_WORD.findall(text)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Sentence(%s)' % reprlib.repr(self.text)

    def __iter__(self):
        return SentenceIterator(self.words)


class SentenceIterator:
    def __init__(self, words):
        self.words = words
        self.index = 0

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            word = self.words[self.index]
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration()
        self.index += 1
        return word

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
s = Sentence('"The time has come," the Walrus said,')
```

you can do:

```
   for i in iter(s):
       print(s)
```

and:

```
   for i in s:
       print(s)
```

if you remove __iter__in iterator,you can only use:

```
 for i in s:
     print(s)
```

Because `iter(s)` is no more an iterator when you remove `__iter__` from the iterator class.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure about the statement:if you delete __iter__ in iterator, that the for loop still works? Mine certainly doesn't... Otherwise, the above answers are great.

Comment: @user7865286  yes,you can remove __iter__ in iterator, in above code snippet,SentenceIterator is  the iterator,you can remove it and run 'for i in s:print s'.