# Why does a class need __iter__() to return an iterator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, iterator

Why does a class need to define `__iter__()` returning self, to get an iterator of the class?

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = 0

    def __next__(self):
        self.state += 1
        if self.state > 4:
            raise StopIteration
        return self.state

myObj = MyClass()
for i in myObj:
    print(i)
```

Console log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   for i in myObj:
TypeError: 'MyClass' object is not iterable
```

the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9884259/4515198, says

> An iterator is an object with a next (Python 2) or `__next__` (Python 3) method.

The task of adding the following:

```
def __iter__(self):
   return self
```

is to return an **iterator**, or an object of the class, which defines the `__next__()` method.

But, isn't the task of returning an object of MyClass (which defines the `__next__()` method) already done by the `__new__()` method, when MyClass is instantiated in the line myObj = MyClass() ?

Won't the objects of a class defining `__next__()` method, be iterators by themselves?

I have studied the questions [What is the use of returning self in the __iter__ method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35657927/4515198) and [Build a Basic Python Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19151/4515198), but I am still unable to understand the reason for having an `__iter__()` method returning self.

Comment: This question seems confused about the difference between an _iterator_ and an _iteratable_.

Answer (score 19):

The answer to the question of **why the *__iter__()* method is necessary** is that for ***for-loops* always start by calling *iter()* on an object** to get an iterator.  That is why even iterators themselved need an *__iter__()* method to work with for-loops.  After *for* calls *iter()*, then it calls *__next__()* on the resulting iterator to obtain a value.

The rules for creating iterables and iterators are:

1) Iterables have an *__iter__()* method that returns an iterator.

2) Iterators have a *__next__()* method that returns a value, that updates the state, and that raises *StopIteration* when complete.

3) Iterators themselves have a *__iter__()* method that returns *self*.  That means that all iterators are self-iterable.

The **benefit of the last rule** for iterators having an *__iter__()* method that returns *self* is that it allows us **to pass around partially consumed iterators**:

```
>>> s = 'hello world'
>>> it = iter(s)
>>> next(it)
'h'
>>> next(it)
'e'
>>> list(it)     # Doesn't start from the beginning
['l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

Here's another example that depends on iterators being self-iterable without restarting:

```
>>> s = 'hello world'
>>> it = iter(s)
>>> list(zip(it, it))
[('h', 'e'), ('l', 'l'), ('o', ' '), ('w', 'o'), ('r', 'l')]
```

**Notes:**

1) An alternative way to make an iterable is to supply a *__getitem__()* method that accepts consecutive indices and raises *IndexError* when complete.  This is how *str* objects iterated in Python 2.

2) Some objects like files are their own iterator.  That means that you can call *next()* directly on a file object. It also means that files cannot have multiple, independent iterators (the file object itself has the state tracking the position within the file).

3) The iterator design pattern described above isn't Python specific.  It is a general purpose design pattern for many OOP languages: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern

Answer (score 5):

> isn't that already done by the `__new__()` method

Nope, `__new__` is just another method, it doesn't automatically create `__iter__` for an object.

> Won't the objects of a class defining `__next__()` method, be iterators by themselves?

Not necessarily, as your first class defining `__next__` but not `__iter__` shows. `__next__` is *needed* if you need to support iteration since it produces the values. `__iter__` is needed since that's what's called on an object in the `for` statement in order for it to get an iterator.

You could have a class that only defines `__next__` and somewhat works (it is limited) but, it needs to be returned from someones `__iter__` . For example, the class `MyClass` returns a class `CustomIter` that only defines `__next__`:

```
class MyClass:
    def __iter__(self): 
        return CustomIter()

class CustomIter(object):

    def __init__(self): 
        self.state = 0

    def __next__(self): 
        self.state += 1
        if self.state > 4:
            raise StopIteration
        return self.state
```

You'll need an `__iter__` defined on an object that will return another object (could be itself) on which `__next__` is defined.

---

If your class defines `__iter__` as:

```
def __iter__(self): return self
```

then you need to define `__next__` on `type(self)` (the class) since you return the instance itself. `__next__` is going to get called on `self` until no more values can be produced.

The other case is when `__iter__` simply returns another object which defines `__next__` (as per my first example). You can alternatively do that by making `__iter__` a generator.

For example:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = 0

    def __iter__(self): 
        for i in range(10): yield i
```

doesn't define a `__next__`. When `iter` is called on it though:

```
g = iter(MyClass())
```

it returns a generator `g` that defines `__next__`:

```
g = iter(MyClass())

g.__next__() # 0
g.__next__() # 1
```

Comment: What I meant to say in "isn't that already done by the `__new__()` method" was that when `__new__()` method has already created an object of MyClass, why do we need to return an object of MyClass again, through `__iter__()`?

Comment: As I get it, a loop like `for` **_necessarily_** calls the `__iter__()` method to get an instance of MyClass, or any class for that matter. Is that the way it works in python?

Comment: If it exists, @thebeliever3 . There's fallback options as stated in the link you have in your question body (e.g, `__getitem__` is attempted if no `__iter__` is found.)

Comment: Note, too, that `__iter__` isn't just returning *an* object of type `MyClass`; it's returning the *same* object that invoked `__iter__` in the first place, because that's the object whose (bound) `__next__` method you want `next` to invoke. For classes that are iterable but not themselves iterators (like `list`), `__iter__` doesn't return the object or necessarily even another object of the same type. (`list.__iter__` returns a brand new object of type `list_iterator` which references the original list.)

Comment: @DimitrisFasarakisHilliard is there a preferred way to implement an iterator? You showed two ways, on the class itself and as a custom class. Is the custom class preferred?