# Do Python iterators formally require an __iter__ method?

Tags: python, iterator

Several places online, including answers in Stack Overflow (such as [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/iterator), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator?rq=1) & [this](https://treyhunner.com/2016/12/python-iterator-protocol-how-for-loops-work/)), mention that Python iterators must implement both the `__next__` method (which I understand) *and* the `__iter__` method. These places rightfully conclude that all iterators are also iterables. Even PyCharm issues a type warning if a variable which is annotated to be a `typing.Iterator` doesn't implement that `__iter__` method.

Contrary to those, the [official Python tutorial section on iterators](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) only mentions the need for a `__next__` method:

> The function returns an iterator object that defines the method `__next__()` which accesses elements in the container one at a time

So my question is: do Python iterators formally need to be iterables on their own? I personally don't understand why this should be true, and why we can't fully separate the requirements for an `Iterable` and an `Iterator`.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator, https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439815/why-does-a-class-need-iter-to-return-an-iterator

Comment: @jonrsharpe Great. If you pass these links as a separate answer I'll accept it.

Comment: The answer below already quotes one of them, and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the tutorial. It glosses over things. If you check the [data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter), you'll see an explicit requirement that iterators support `__iter__`:

> The iterator objects themselves are required to support the following two methods, which together form the *iterator protocol*:
>
> `iterator.__iter__()`
>
> Return the iterator object itself. This is required to allow both containers and iterators to be used with the for and in statements. This method corresponds to the tp_iter slot of the type structure for Python objects in the Python/C API.
>
> `iterator.__next__()`
>
> ...

Python easily *could* have been designed to make iterators non-iterable, the way Java did, but that would have been counterproductive. Iterating over iterators is extremely common and standard in Python, and it was always intended to be.

Having to stick some kind of `iterwrapper` around iterators in every `for` loop would be like having to stick some kind of `addablewrapper` around your integers every time you wanted to add two integers.

Comment: Note that you can easily subvert that contract and make an object whose `__iter__` returns something that has only a `__next__` method, not `__iter__`; you can then still iterate over the initial object.