# Define a iterable class supporting two or more simultaneous iterating

Tags: python, iterator

I'm not sure if this title is good..Hope someone could help to change it.

I'm trying to define an `molecule` class, and hope it can iterate over its atoms.
I searched how people define an iterable class, and it may look like this:

```
class molecule(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
         self.__pointer=0
         # ...something else
    def __iter__(self):
         self.__pointer=0
         return self
    def __next__(self):
         self.__pointer+=1
         if self.__pointer<=self.natoms: # self.natoms is defined somewhere
               return self[self.__pointer]   # suppose __getitem__ is defined to return an atom object
         else:
               raise StopIteration("Exceeded all atoms")
```

It works well:

```
 >>> ben=molecule('ben') #defined a molecule
 >>> ben.addatom(...) # and defined some atoms
 >>> ite=iter(ben)
 >>> for atom in ite:
 ...     print(atom)
 ...
 # atom objects are correctly printed here
```

However, I found it cannot work in two iterators, if they exist simultaneously.

```
>>> ite=iter(ben)
>>> next(ite)
# atom1
>>> next(ite)
# atom2
>>> ite2=iter(ben)
>>> next(ite)
# atom1 again, where atom3 is expected
>>> next(ite2)
# atom2, where atom1 is expected
```

This is not a surprise because the two iterators share a same `self.__pointer`, so defining a new iterator will renew the pointer to zero.

I had a look at this page [How to make class iterable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/how-to-make-class-iterable), and most of them use a `self.__pointer` within the class, which raises my question.
I guess if the `pointer` be an attribute of the iterator(`ite` or `ite2`) but not of the iterated object itself (`molecule`), then this problem could be solved.

Hope someone can give some help:) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `__iter__` to return new iterator object every time when it's called.

```
class molecule_iterator(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.pointer = 0
        self.obj = obj

    def __next__(self):
        self.pointer += 1  # Are you sure to do this here?
        if self.pointer < self.obj.natoms:
            return self.obj[self.pointer]
        raise StopIteration()


class molecule(object):
    ...

    def __iter__(self):
        return molecule_iterator(self)

    ...
```

Or, you can use [`yield` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement) which does not require you to define `__next__`. Because `__iter__()` will return a new generator iterator:

```
def __iter__(self):
    for i in range(self.natoms):
        yield self[i + 1]
```

DEMO: https://ideone.com/TK78Ml

Comment: > Make `__iter__` to return new iterator object every time when it's called.  << How to do this?   while using `yield` looks good.

Comment: @RuixingWang, I updated the answer to include the code for the first option. (return new iterator instance)

Comment: Cool answer.  For the comment `#Are you sure`, yes, since I count atoms from 1 but not zero:)   Thanks!