# How to read Python reader iteratively outside of for construct?

Tags: python, csv, iterator

I wrote this code and it prints rows sequentially:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    rder = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in rder:
        print(row)
```

Is it possible to access `rder` with `hasNext` and `next` fashion, i.e. without `for` construct? For example, how to skip first row?

The question is general, I would like to understand, what does it mean to be able to stay before `in`. In Java this means being of [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface and I can easily find it's documentation and know, what I can do with it.

In Python there is no information that I can find about what is returned by the `reader` function and I don't know what I can do with it except [what is written in example](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html#csv.reader). And that example is written to only use it with `for`.

Can I choose to choose something else?

Comment: `rder` is an iterator.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator

Comment: How would I know, that `reader()` returns iterator? Usage in `for` implies this?

Comment: Yes, `for ... in X` implies `X` is an iterator of some sort.  Python has a fairly rich variety of things which can be iterated over.

Comment: `X` being usable in `for whatever in X` implies that `X` is an *iterable*. That might be an iterator (which wouldn't count as an iterable in Java), or it might be some sort of reusable iterable like a list or a Python 3 range object.

Comment: `rder` is not inherently an iterator; it is only an iterator because Python can use a text fie (and many other objects that return strings) as an iterator.

Answer (score 3):

`csv.reader` returns an [iterator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator).

**The iterator can be used in a `for` loop via `in`:**

So this:

```
import csv
rder = csv.reader(my_csv(), delimiter=' ')
for row in rder:
    print(row)
```

gives:

```
['A', 'header', 'row']
['some', 'data']
['some', 'more', 'data']
['A', 'footer']
```

**The iterator can be read inside the for loop using `next()`:**

If we need to consume a row inside of the for loop we can do:

```
rder = csv.reader(my_csv(), delimiter=' ')
for row in rder:
    print(row)
    print('Grabbed one:', next(rder))
```

To give:

```
['A', 'header', 'row']
Grabbed one: ['some', 'data']
['some', 'more', 'data']
Grabbed one: ['A', 'footer']
```

**The iterator can also be used outside of the for loop:**

```
rder = csv.reader(my_csv(), delimiter=' ')
print('first one:', next(rder))
print('second one:', next(rder))
for row in rder:
    print(row)
```

Will give:

```
first one: ['A', 'header', 'row']
second one: ['some', 'data']
['some', 'more', 'data']
['A', 'footer']
```

**Test Data:**

```
from io import StringIO

def my_csv():
    return StringIO('\n'.join([x.strip() for x in u"""
        A header row
        some data
        some more data
        A footer
    """.split('\n')[1:-1]]))
```

Comment: Bleh, SO Docs. Just looking at the first paragraph of what the link goes to, I can already see several mistakes. The [real Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/) aren't the greatest, but they're usually better than that.

Answer (score 1):

[csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) returns an iterator based on the underlying objects iterator protocol. It will not work as an iterator if the underlying object does not support iteration.

If you use a text file, that is based on what is causing `next` to function for a text file (usually a `\n` sequence but not always...)

You *can* write a loop Python that is not based on the `for` protocol. Instead, you use `try/except` and catch the `StopIteration` exception:

```
with open('file.csv') as csvfile:
    rder = csv.reader(csvfile)
    while True:
        try:
            row=next(rder)  
            print row
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

But specifically, to get a header, it is probably better to do:

```
with open('file.csv') as csvfile:
    rder = csv.reader(csvfile)
    header=next(rder)
    print header
    for row in rder:
        print row
```

Or, with Python3 you can shorten that to:

```
with open('/tmp/file.csv') as csvfile:
    rder = csv.reader(csvfile)
    header, *rows=[row for row in rder]
```

But you can also use a non-file object, like a string with csv and records separate by a separate delimiter:

```
>>> s='A,B,C|1,2,3|4,5,6'
>>> import csv
>>> for row in csv.reader(s.split("|")):
...    print row
... 
['A', 'B', 'C']
['1', '2', '3']
['4', '5', '6']
```

In this case, `next` is moving to the next list element that is the result of the `.split()`