# Iterator custom class, wrapping over a OrderedDict, confused about __next__

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration

I realised I still don't quite understand how to implement an iterator class. So a class where one can "for-loop" over some of its contents.

I have looked at these answers (I still don't get it):

[What exactly are Python's iterator, iterable, and iteration protocols?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols)

[Build a Basic Python Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator)

As far as I understand, an iterable is one that implements `__iter__` and returns an iterator which is something that has `__next__` implemented.
From this I somehow understood that if I want my class to be an iterator, and iterable. I must define `__iter__` to return self, and have `__next__` defined. Am I wrong so far?

Here is a scaffold for my class:

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, low, high):
        self.store = OrderedDict()  # it is imported (ommited)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.store[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
        # Option 3
        return self.store

    def __next__(self):
        # Option 1 
        for key in self.store:
            return key
        # Option 2
        for key in self.store.keys():
            return key
```

Tried the above options, none worked. :(

What happens is I have some py.tests prepared to test the iteration if it works correctly, just a simple for loop, nothing fancy. And the tests just run forever (or longer then my patience < 5 min), but the mock class has 5 items, so it should not take long.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your concepts mixed up. You say

> I realised I still don't quite understand how to implement an iterator class. So a class where one can "for-loop" over some of its contents.

but that's not how things work. If you just want to be able to perform `for` loops over instances of your class, you almost certainly shouldn't be making your instances iterators directly. You should write an `__iter__` method that returns an iterator, either manually or by `yield`ing, and you should *not* write a `__next__`:

```
# Returning an iterator manually:
class Wrapper:
    ...
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.store)

# or with yield:
class Wrapper:
    ...
    def __iter__(self):
        for thing in self.store:
            yield thing
```

Iterators are technically iterable, but only once. To write an iterator, you would have `__iter__` return `self` and have `__next__` return the next item on each call, or raise `StopIteration` when the items are exhausted (and continue to raise `StopIteration` on any further calls). I'll write an iterator over the half-open interval [0, 10), since writing one for an OrderedDict would just delegate to the OrderedDict's iterator for everything too directly to be instructive:

```
class Iterator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = 0
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        if self.state == 10:
            raise StopIteration
        self.state += 1
        return self.state - 1
```

Writing iterators manually is unusual even when you do want an iterator, though; it's much more common to use `yield`:

```
def iterator():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i

# or managing the index manually, to show what it would be like without range:
def iterator():
    i = 0
    while i < 10:
        yield i
        i += 1
```

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank you. I did not really understand those things before. So if all I want is "for-loop" functionality, my `__iter__` returning `iter(self.store)` will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the following changes:

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, low, high):
        self.store = OrderedDict() 
        self.__iter = None  # maintain state of self as iterator

    def __iter__(self):
        if self.__iter is None:
            self.__iter = iter(self.store)
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            return next(self.__iter)
        except StopIteration:   # support repeated iteration
            self.__iter = None  
            raise
```

`__next__` should return the next element of an iterator that is being iterated. And your `__iter__` method should return `self` to properly implement the protocol. This ensures for instance, that a call to `next` during a loop drives forward the same iterator as the loop:

```
for x in wrapper:
    # do stuff with x
    next(wrapper)  # skip one
```

For most purposes, impementing `__iter__` should suffice:

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, low, high):
        self.store = OrderedDict() 

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.store)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. It also seems to work without the state maintainance. Could you explain why it is needed?

Comment: you can always do `for x in wrapper` (calls `__iter__` implicitly), but `next(wrapper)` (calls `__next__` implicitly) should not work properly without maintaining state.

Comment: Your `__iter__` and `__next__` aren't consistent; you seem to want `Wrapper` instances to be iterators, judging by the presence of `__next__`, but you're not returning `self` from `__iter__`.

Comment: Yes, this does not correctly implement the iterator protocol. Since this class defines an iterator, `__next__` must return `self`. Likely, the OP simply should be defining an iterator, and rather, it should define an iterable that simply delegates to the internal dict as you've done here with no `__next__` method

Comment: @user2357112 What do you mean exactly? Yeah my class definition was wrong, but the schwobaseggl solution seemed to make it work perfectly.

Comment: Not really sure what you all mean now. My `__iter__` would return the `iter(self.store)` and my `__next__` should return self? Why?

Comment: @user2357112 True, I edited my answer to implement the protocol properly.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You mean `__iter__` should return `self`. True, I edited my answer.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Whoops, yes, `__iter__` should return `self` is what I meant.