# How to return an iterable object in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a tree. I have several tasks that involving scanning the whole tree.

I would like to write a function, say `scanTree ()` for instance that will scan a tree in a particular order, then returns an iterable object.

The idea is:

```
def task1 (self):
  x = self.scanTree ()
  for y in x:
    do_something1(y)

def task2 (self):
  x = self.scanTree ()
  for y in x:
    do_something2(y)
```

But I don't know what kind of object I can return in function `scanTree`.

Could you give me some hints?

Thank you very much,

Comment: Read up about generators and the `yield` keyword.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build a Basic Python Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator)

Comment: @MikeScotty The accepted answer to that is rather dated, takes an unnecessary detour through the low-level iterator protocol, and misses out on the use of `yield from` which is very useful for recursive traversal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a job for [generators](http://thepythonguru.com/python-generators/). Assuming your btree class looks like this:

```
class BTree:
  def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
    self._value = value
    self._left = left
    self._right = right
```

You could then write a `scanTree()` that does in-order traversal like this:

```
def scanTree(self):
  '''
  Traverse the binary tree in-order
  '''
  if self._left is not None:
    yield from self._left.scanTree()
  yield self._value
  if self._right is not None:
    yield from self._right.scanTree()
```

You then use it like this:

```
>>> l = BTree(1)
>>> r = BTree(3)
>>> t = BTree(2, l, r)
>>> it = t.scanTree()
>>> it
<generator object BTree.scanTree at 0x7fc20602a728>
>>> list(it)
[1, 2, 3]
```

There's a bunch of concepts involved here to understand this in-depth, but the basic idea is very intuitive: you write the same loop as if you meant to print the elements in the order you want, except you use `yield` instead of printing, and `yield from` anytime you recurse.