# How to iterate with different values in for loop?

Tags: python, loops, optimization, iteration

I want to know whether we can specify the next value to increment in "*for loop*" by hard coding?

Currently, I am iterating this way: 
Eg:

```
for i in range(0, 10, 2):
    print(i)
```

output will be `0,2,4,6,8`

If I want a value of `5` and `7` along with increments of `2`, how can I do that?

Eg:

```
for i in range(0, 10, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8):
```

Comment: can you provide an example of the input you have and the output you want?

Comment: You could do it ugly and have `indexes = [2,4,5,6,7,8]`, then `for i in indexes` (or skip the `indexes` alltoghether and do `for i in [2,4,5,6,7,8]`)

Comment: Thanks! But, if I need to parse 1 through 1000 with exceptions of increments in between, is there a way other than specifying indexes?

Comment: What are those exceptions?

Comment: Ex: for i in range(1, 1000, 20); I need i value of 178, 235, 650 in between. Can I do that in for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this code is for you:
Using generators comprehension:

```
pred = i%2 is 0
forced_values = [5, 7]

list((i for i in range(0, 10) if pred or i in forced_values))
# output: [0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

or equivalently:

```
sorted(list(range(0, 10, 2)) + forced_values)
```

### Comparison of execution times:

Benchmark:

```
n = 10000000 # size of range values
m = 10000000 # size of forced_value list
```

#### 1. Solution with generators comprehension:

```
%%timeit
list((i for i in range(0, n) if i%2 is 0 or i in range(0, m)))
# 3.47 s ± 265 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

#### 2. Solution with sorting:

```
%%timeit
sorted(list(range(0, n, 2)) + list(range(0, m)))
# 1.59 s ± 11.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

or with unordered list, if the order is not important:

```
%%timeit
list(range(0, n, 2)) + list(range(0, m))
# 1.03 s ± 109 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

#### 3. Solution proposed by @blhsing with [more_itertools](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/) package, and specifically [collate](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.collate) function:

```
%%timeit
l = []
for i in collate(range(0, n, 2), range(0, m)):
    l.append(i)
# 6.89 s ± 886 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The best solution, even on very large lists, seems to be the second one that is 2 to 4 times faster than the other proposed solutions.

Comment: Skip the list part though and keep it a generator. 
`for i in (i for i in range(0,1000) if i%20 is 0 or i in [178, 235, 650]): print(i)`

Comment: Perfect! I'm glad I helped you. I changed the code a bit to make it clearer :-)

Comment: @micke Obviously it can keep the generator or turn it into a list. The advice is to turn the generator into a list only when it is actually necessary to work on the individual values. All in your previous comment when you do `for i in (i for i in range (0,1000) if i% 20 is 0 or i in [178, 235, 650]): print (i)`

you're implicitly turning the generator into a list :-)

Comment: Personally, I'm disappointed that you gave in to @blhsing. You may have been intimidated by his relatively high rep. The supposed "inefficiency" of the `sorted` function surely should not be a serious consideration for such small list sizes. Readability is much more important than such a tiny improvement in efficiency. You felt the `sorted` solution was clearer, and I agree with you.

Comment: @JohnY In what way is `collate(range(0, 10, 2), (5, 7))` less clear than `sorted(tuple(range(0, 10, 2)) + (5, 7))`?

Comment: @blhsing If you want to update the answer shortly by comparing the execution times of the two solutions, so we can discuss them. What are you saying?

Comment: And Massifox, your `sorted` solution is faster than @blhsing's by about an order of magnitude, according to *their own timings* (see comments on their answer).

Comment: Rolled back the edit since using the `sorted` function implemented in C is the most efficient approach for the OP's use case with small lists.

Comment: Yes, I am now publishing tests to compare the 3 solutions (my two solutions and the one based on collate)

Comment: My only nitpick with this answer as it stands is that the `sorted` solution isn't what I'd personally call "equivalent", because of algorithmic differences. Yes, they produce the same output, but so does the literal `[0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`, which is fastest of all.

Comment: For those with insufficient rep to see it, @blhsing deleted their answer, which mentioned the useful [`more_itertools`](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/) package, and specifically the [`collate`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.collate) function.

Comment: Thanks @JohnY! I updated my answer by adding comparisons on execution times. I hope I have done a good job.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, here are some relevant comments:

> if I need to parse 1 through 1000 with exceptions of increments in between, is there a way other than specifying indexes?

> Ex: for i in range(1, 1000, 20); I need i value of 178, 235, 650 in between. Can I do that in for loop?

The *technical* answer is: yes and no. **Yes**, because of course you can do it in a `for` loop. **No**, because there is no way around specifying the exceptions. (Otherwise they wouldn't be *exceptions*, would they?)

You still use a `for` loop, because Python's `for` loop is not really about indices or ranges. It's about iterating over arbitrary objects. It *so happens* that the simple numeric `for` loop that many other languages have is most directly translated into Python as a loop over a range. But really, a Python `for` loop is simply of the form

```
for x in y:
    # do stuff here
```

And the loop iterates over `y`, no matter what `y` is, as long as it's iterable, with `x` taking the value of one element of `y` on each iteration. That's it.

But, what you seem to be *really after* is a way to loop over a bunch of numbers that *mostly* follow a simple pattern. I would probably do it like this:

```
values = list(range(1, 1000, 20)) + [178, 235, 650]
for i in sorted(values):
    print(i)
```

Or, if you don't mind a longer line:

```
for i in sorted(list(range(1, 1000, 20)) + [178, 235, 650]):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the technical briefing, helps me understand concepts better.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the for loop a list:

```
for i in [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]:
```

You could also create a custom iterator if it's following an algorithm. That's described in another answer here: [Build a Basic Python Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator).