# Is it possible to make a class object iterable in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm wondering if it's possible to make a class object iterable in Python (ie. a subclass of `type`, NOT an instance of a class).

I've tried the following code:

```
class Foo:
    @classmethod
    def __iter__(cls):
        yield 1


print(next(Foo.__iter__()))  # prints 1
print(next(iter(Foo)))  # TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build a Basic Python Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator)

Comment: No, that answer is about making a class instance iterable, I'm asking about a class object (a subclass of `type`)

Comment: Most class objects are not subclasses of `type`. All class objects are *instances* of `type`.

Comment: thanks @Tomerikoo that indeed answers the question. It didn't turn up in search unfortunately.

Comment: It is certainly possible because a class is nothing more than an instance of its metaclass (`type` for ordinary ones, but you can customize it). Simply I cannot imagine a real world use case...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's possible with metaclasses.

```
class Foo(type):
    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.baz


class Bar(metaclass=Foo):
    baz = 1


print(type(Bar))  # prints "<class '__main__.Foo'>"
print(next(Bar.__iter__()))  # prints "1"
print(next(iter(Bar)))  # prints "1"
```

Thanks @DanielB for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: This question was asked already and this answer also exists there. Instead of answering, you should either mark your question as duplicate or delete it...

Comment: ye, i've just seen your comment with the other question

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible, as it would imply that all `type` objects are iterable - as you stated, classes are of type `type`. The underlying reason for this is that the `__iter__` method is looked up on the type, not the value. E.g., in:

```
for i in Foo:
    print(i)
```

Python will look up `type(Foo).__iter__`, not `Foo.__iter__`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer this gave me an idea to make it work with metaclasses.