# In python how does an iter() method makes an iterable an iterator? How does __next__ method magically appears in the directory of an iterator?

Tags: python, iterator, iterable

For example

```
l1= [1,2,3,4,5]
i_l1 = iter(list)
```

what did the iter() function do to l1 that made i_l1 an iterator?
can someone provide the source code for iter() function?
Also how does the **next** method magically appeared in the i_l1 directory after passing l1 as an argument to iter() funtion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build a Basic Python Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator)

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) (also the links therein) on this seems to be fairly reasonable?